# HTML table with fixed headers and a fixed column?

Tags: javascript, html, css, html-table

Is there a CSS/JavaScript technique to display a long HTML table such that the column headers stay fixed on-screen and the first coloumn stay fixed and scroll with the data.

I want to be able to scroll through the contents of the table, but to always be able to see the column headers at the top and the first column on the left.

If there is a jQuery plugin that would be great! If it helps the only browser I care about is Firefox.

Comment: Partial dup: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/673153/html-table-with-fixed-headers

Comment: Doesn't seems like a duplicate as this question requires fixed column as well.

Comment: I voted to reopen this question out of principle.  Dozens of upvotes and favorit'ing, apparently someone finds it useful.  Yes it requires a long answer.  That's what jfiddle and other similar tools are for.

Comment: @KickingLettuce Popularity !== on-topic. If the question is reopened it will just be closed again.

Comment: Google brought me to this question on my first searches, but the answers are outdated and not very satisfying. I eventually found the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50516259/982107

Comment: I don't see why this question is closed. The problem is clearly defined. The question should accept answers with potentially more modern techniques.

Answer (score 19):

Working example of [link posted by pranav](http://fixed-header-using-jquery.blogspot.com/2009/05/scrollable-table-with-fixed-header-and.html):

http://jsbin.com/nolanole/1/edit?html,js,output

FYI: Tested in IE 6, 7, & 8 (compatibility mode on or off), FF 3 & 3.5, Chrome 2.  Not screen-reader-friendly (headers aren't part of content table).

EDIT 5/5/14: moved example to jsBin.  This is old, but amazingly still works in current Chrome, IE, and Firefox (though IE and Firefox might require some adjustments to row heights).

Comment: doesn't work for me in winxp ie8 or ff3.6

Comment: The link to the jQuery library hosted on jQuery.com changed, and their redirect was incorrect... so it stopped working in ALL browsers.

I've fixed the link to point to the file on Google's servers instead - hopefully that one should be more reliable.

Comment: Thanks. This helped me a lot. I had to modify the code to use setTimeout() to get it to work with larger tables, but this is a nice example.

Answer (score 3):

The **[jQuery DataTables plug-in](http://datatables.net/index)** is one excellent way to achieve excel-like fixed column(s) and headers.

Note the examples section of the site and the "extras".
http://datatables.net/examples/
http://datatables.net/extras/

The "Extras" section has tools for fixed columns and fixed headers.

**Fixed Columns**
http://datatables.net/extras/fixedcolumns/
(I believe the example on this page is the one most appropriate for your question.)

**Fixed Header**
http://datatables.net/extras/fixedheader/
(Includes an example with a full page spreadsheet style layout: http://datatables.net/release-datatables/extras/FixedHeader/top_bottom_left_right.html)

Comment: note: from my experience (correct me if I'm wrong), it only works if all of your table cells have `colSpan` and `rowSpan` = 1.

Answer (score 2):

I see this, although an old question, is a pretty good place to plug my own script:

http://code.google.com/p/js-scroll-table-header/

It just works with no configuration and is really easy to setup.

Comment: I have a feeling that assigned unique ids to every row when there could be thousands of rows might not be the best solution.

Answer (score 1):

If what you want is to have the headers stay put while the data in the table scrolls vertically, you should implement a <tbody> styled with "overflow-y: auto" like this:

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Header1</th>
       . . . 
    </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody style="height: 300px; overflow-y: auto"> 
     <tr>
       . . .
     </tr>
     . . .
   </tbody>
 </table>
```

If the <tbody> content grows taller than the desired height, it will start scrolling. However, the headers will stay fixed at the top regardless of the scroll position.

Comment: thanks, that helps with the fixed header part but what about the fixed column?

Comment: overflow-y is ms specific. You'll have to use a plain overflow:auto.

Comment: Would it be possible to do two colgroups and give the second one overflow:auto, to achieve the fixed first col?

Comment: @levik: does not work in almost all browsers at least using HTML 5 DOCTYPE in standrad mode

Comment: This does not work...

Comment: @Thomas Ahie Good question, did you get any feedback?

Comment: It doesn't work at all !

Answer (score 1):

In this answer there is also the best answer I found to your question:

[HTML table with fixed headers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/673153/html-table-with-fixed-headers/673162#673162)

**and based on pure CSS**.

Answer (score 0):

I have created something which has fixed header, fixed footer, fixed left column and also fixed right column. This only works fine in IE. As most of the users are still using IE this can be helpful. Please find the code here in [Scrollable Table](http://s7u.blogspot.com/2008/07/dear-friends-i-want-to-discuss-about.html). Please let me your suggestions.

Meanwhile I am working to fix columns in other browser. I will keep you posted. :-)

Comment: This isn't a great solution,  IE has stopped supporting CSS expressions: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc304082%28VS.85%29.aspx#expressions

Comment: "most of the users are still using IE" LOL :D

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
   $(document).ready(function () {
   $("#GridHeader table").html($('#<%= GridView1.ClientID %>').html());
   $("#GridHeader table tbody .rows").remove();
   $('#<%= GridView1.ClientID %> tr:first th').hide();
});
</script>

<div id="GridHeader">
    <table></table>
</div>

<div style="overflow: auto; height:400px;">
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" />
</div>
```

Comment: Is it possible to use this method with "responsive" columns (no fixed width defined)?

Answer (score 0):

Not quite perfect, but it got me closer than some of the top answers here.

Two different tables, one with the header, and the other, wrapped with a div with the content

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr><th>Stuff</th><th>Second Stuff</th></tr>
  </thead>
</table>
<div style="height: 600px; overflow: auto;">
  <table>
    <tbody>
      //Table
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

I know you can [do it for MSIE](http://web.tampabay.rr.com/bmerkey/examples/locked-column-csv.html) and [this limited example](http://www.whirlywiryweb.com/q/dhtmlgems.asp) seems to work for firefox (not sure how extensible the technique is).

Comment: First linked didn't work for me. Second one does now show how to produce fixed first column.

Comment: Both links in answer are dead.

Answer (score -2):

The first column has a scrollbar on the cell right below the headers

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <th> Header 1</th>
        <th> Header 2</th>
        <th> Header 3</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div style="width: 50; height:30; overflow-y: scroll"> 
                    Tklasdjf alksjf asjdfk jsadfl kajsdl fjasdk fljsaldk 
                    fjlksa djflkasjdflkjsadlkf jsakldjfasdjfklasjdflkjasdlkfjaslkdfjasdf
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>
                Hello world
            </td>
            <td> Hello world2
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I think you've misunderstood what's being asked. We want to be able to scroll to different cells in a (large) table.

Answer (score -2):

[YUI DataTable](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/datatable/)

I don't know if YUI DT has this feature but I won't be surprised if it does.

Comment: Thanks I took a look at that. It does have a scrolling table but that does have a fixed header but not the fixed coloumn that I need.

http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/examples/datatable/dt_fixedscroll.html

Comment: yeah, I couldn't find that either from their list of examples.

Answer (score -3):

Here is a good jQuery plugin, working in all browsers!

You have a fixed header table without fixing its width.

Check it: https://github.com/benjaminleouzon/tablefixedheader

Disclaimer: I am the author of the plugin.

Comment: Guess, the correct URL here would be http://www.fixedheadertable.com/