# HTML table with horizontal scrolling (first column fixed)

Tags: html, overflow, html-table, fixed

I have been trying to think of a way to make a table with a fixed first column (and the rest of the table with a horizontal overflow)  I saw a post which had a similar question. but the fixed column bit did not seem to be resolved.  Help?

Comment: I'd like to expand this question a little: a friend of mine wants to make a table which wouldn't scale to more than 100% of the page, but would have more than two columns that together should be scrollable in case they need more horizontal space than there is. In effect, this should be similar to Frozen columns in MS Excel. Is that possible?

Comment: See my answer on similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17557830/1763149

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I have a similar table styled like so:

```html
<table style="width:100%; table-layout:fixed">
  <tr>
    <td style="width: 150px">Hello, World!</td>
    <td>
      <div>
        <pre style="margin:0; overflow:scroll">My preformatted content</pre>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: This answer would really benefit from a demo here.

Comment: [JSFIDDLE demo](https://jsfiddle.net/dx65qwa3/) so that it's more clear what happens here

Comment: That only scrolls a single cell…

Comment: I don't know why this is the accepted answer. The question says: and the rest of the table, which in my point of view includes more than one column...

Comment: and the columns should be in sync with the headers, like if the columns scroll; headers should scroll too with the columns. But I don't think they both will be in sync after implementing this solution

Comment: this is best option

Answer (score 126):

How about:

```css
table {
  table-layout: fixed; 
  width: 100%;
  *margin-left: -100px; /*ie7*/
}
td, th {
  vertical-align: top;
  border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 100px;
}
.fix {
  position: absolute;
  *position: relative; /*ie7*/
  margin-left: -100px;
  width: 100px;
}
.outer {
  position: relative;
}
.inner {
  overflow-x: scroll;
  overflow-y: visible;
  width: 400px; 
  margin-left: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th class=fix></th>
        <th>Col 1</th>
        <th>Col 2</th>
        <th>Col 3</th>
        <th>Col 4</th>
        <th class="fix">Col 5</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th class=fix>Header A</th>
        <td>col 1 - A</td>
        <td>col 2 - A (WITH LONGER CONTENT)</td>
        <td>col 3 - A</td>
        <td>col 4 - A</td>
        <td class=fix>col 5 - A</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th class=fix>Header B</th>
        <td>col 1 - B</td>
        <td>col 2 - B</td>
        <td>col 3 - B</td>
        <td>col 4 - B</td>
        <td class=fix>col 5 - B</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th class=fix>Header C</th>
        <td>col 1 - C</td>
        <td>col 2 - C</td>
        <td>col 3 - C</td>
        <td>col 4 - C</td>
        <td class=fix>col 5 - C</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

You can test it out in this jsbin: http://jsbin.com/uxecel/4/edit

Comment: Simple but effective solution to my query!

Comment: This basically works for me but I'd like to start out with the right-most columns of the scrolling div visible. My column titles are dates, with the most-recent date on the far right, and I'd like that to be visible when the <table> is first displayed. Is there any way to do this programmatically? Is there a way to programmatically move the horizontal scroll bar in either direction? I'd like to have always-available "scroll left" and "scroll right" buttons at the top of the table, since the browser-supported scroll bar is at the bottom and not always immediately visible.

Comment: I saw it has a big gap between header column and data columns when I set width of table > all data columns width,does anybody know why and how to fix it?  please see here: http://jsbin.com/sesurutojo/edit?output

Comment: If I use paging via ajax and I have to go to next page then the scroll does not work and all the table properties are lost. How can I get the same table UI but with some ajax request?

Comment: This seems to work only if vertical scrolling is not required. For my case there are many rows so scrolling vertically will only scroll the row data but not the row header fixed in this way using position absolute.

Comment: @skube : how to set height for the based on content in fixed column

Comment: @blahdiblah :how to set height for the based on content in fixed column

Comment: what about if there is paging?

Comment: @bruce I think that vertical scrolling can work if you make the table `position: relative` and then put it in a div that scrolls. That way, the absolute positioning is scrolled along with the rest of the table.

Comment: @w00t I using rowspan but once i use this code my rowspan doesn't work anymore. Do you know by any chance inner or outer class will affect rowspan

Answer (score 22):

Based on skube's approach, I found the minimal set of CSS I needed was:

```css
.horizontal-scroll-except-first-column {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
}

.horizontal-scroll-except-first-column > table {
  margin-left: 8em;
}

.horizontal-scroll-except-first-column > table > * > tr > th:first-child,
.horizontal-scroll-except-first-column > table > * > tr > td:first-child {
  position: absolute;
  width: 8em;
  margin-left: -8em;
  background: #ccc;
}

.horizontal-scroll-except-first-column > table > * > tr > th,
.horizontal-scroll-except-first-column > table > * > tr > td {
  /* Without this, if a cell wraps onto two lines, the first column
   * will look bad, and may need padding. */
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="horizontal-scroll-except-first-column">
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>FIXED</td> <td>22222</td> <td>33333</td> <td>44444</td> <td>55555</td> <td>66666</td> <td>77777</td> <td>88888</td> <td>99999</td> <td>AAAAA</td> <td>BBBBB</td> <td>CCCCC</td> <td>DDDDD</td> <td>EEEEE</td> <td>FFFFF</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Great and comprehensible, nice

Comment: This only works if all the columns in a row are the same height. If the second column has a taller height for example, you can see it when it goes "behind" the first column. Any ideas on how to fix that?

Answer (score 9):

You can use below table style to have horizontal scrolling table with fixed first column.

```css
table,
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.table-style {
  overflow-x: auto;
}

.table-style tr th:first-child {
  position: sticky;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 2;
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="table-style">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>_col1_row1_</th>
        <th>_col2_row1_</th>
        <th>_col3_row1_</th>
        <th>_col4_row1_</th>
        <th>_col5_row1_</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th>_col1_row2_</th>
        <td>_col2_row2_</td>
        <td>_col3_row2_</td>
        <td>_col4_row2_</td>
        <td>_col5_row2_</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>_col1_row3_</th>
        <td>_col2_row3_</td>
        <td>_col3_row3_</td>
        <td>_col4_row3_</td>
        <td>_col5_row3_</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>_col1_row4_</th>
        <td>_col2_row4_</td>
        <td>_col3_row4_</td>
        <td>_col4_row4_</td>
        <td>_col5_row4_</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>_col1_row5_</th>
        <td>_col2_row5_</td>
        <td>_col3_row5_</td>
        <td>_col4_row5_</td>
        <td>_col5_row5_</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

Answer (score 8):

Use jQuery DataTables plug-in, it supports fixed header and columns.
This example adds fixed column support to the html table "example":

http://datatables.net/extensions/fixedcolumns/

For two fixed columns:

http://www.datatables.net/release-datatables/extensions/FixedColumns/examples/two_columns.html

Comment: Fixing left hand-side columns is done by using the leftColumns initialisation parameter. This link works http://www.datatables.net/extensions/fixedcolumns/ (today)

Answer (score 5):

Here's an example with fixed first and last columns.  Sticky works better than absolute positioning for expanding the rows when the cells have more content.

Note - this also works with rowspan table cells.  The table holds its correct shape.

```css
.wrapper {
  overflow-x:scroll;
  width:100%; 
}
table {
  table-layout: fixed; 
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  background: white;
}
tr {
  border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
}
td, th {
  vertical-align: top;
  text-align: left;
  width:150px;
  padding: 5px;
}
.fix {
  position:sticky;
  background: white;
}
.fix:first-child {
  left:0;
  width:180px;
}
.fix:last-child {
  right:0;
  width:120px;
}
```

```html
  <div class="wrapper">
    <table>
      <thead>
        <th class='fix'>Fixed</th>
        <th>Col 1</th>
        <th>Col 2</th>
        <th>Col 3</th>
        <th>Col 4</th>
        <th>Col 5</th>
        <th class='fix'>Fixed</th>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td class='fix'>First Content</td>
          <td>A1</td>
          <td>A2 (with longer content)</td>
          <td>A3</td>
          <td>A4</td>
          <td>A5</td>
          <td class='fix'>Last Content</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class='fix'>First Content (with longer content)</td>
          <td>B1</td>
          <td>B2</td>
          <td>B3</td>
          <td>B4</td>
          <td>B5</td>
          <td class='fix'>Last Content</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class='fix'>First Content</td>
          <td>C1</td>
          <td>C2</td>
          <td>C3</td>
          <td>C4</td>
          <td>C5</td>
          <td class='fix'>Last Content (with longer content)</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
```

Example to play with: https://jsbin.com/qawidijigi/edit?html,css,output

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at this JQuery plugin:

http://fixedheadertable.com

It adds vertical (fixed header row) **or horizontal** (fixed first column) scrolling to an existing HTML table. There is a demo you can check for both cases of scrolling.

Comment: note: this relies on obsoleted features in jquery and has not been updated since about 1 year

Comment: @HaykSaakian Looks like that project is being updated again now? Says this year, and jQuery version 1.7 is required.