# Absolutely positioned column not visible

Tags: html, overflow, css-position, css-tables

Trying to get a column to freeze on my table. The answer by skube for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3402295/html-table-with-horizontal-scrolling-first-column-fixed) is the closest to what I need. However, I need to go one div deeper. This causes the absolutely positioned column to not show though it is positioned correctly.

Here is the example that is not showing colA (Header A, Header B and Header C): http://jsbin.com/uxecel/667/

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not visible because you have `left:-100px` on `.colA`

<strike>Remove that style, and it works as (I think) you expect.</strike>

**update:** sorry:

Set `left:0px` on `.colA`. Also, you won't need `left:-100px` on the table for ie7.

Comment: That does make it visible but then the colA column is on top of my first column.

Comment: Accepting this as the answer, though it does not fix the problem. The question and example code had to be changed significantly in order to make it work. As a result, the question was not even valid in the first place. Thanks!