# How to make first and last column scrollable in table and rest of the column fixed?

Tags: html, css

I was looking into this post

https://stackoverflow.com/a/14486644/4366769

[image]

But in this solution only middle columns are scrollable and first and last column fixed.

I just need reverse means first 2 and last 2 colums scrollable and middle 2 columns non-scrollable

I have this but no luck https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FHJPEP70627P

Comment: @NikhilNanjappa no I didn't try with any library . Looking for pure css solution

Comment: A simple way to implement this is making 3 tables with in one table having 3 columns.

Comment: Pure CSS I'm afraid is not possible. Horizontally splitting the scrolls amongst the table columns goes against the table structural logic. Without libraries, the best solution I can suggest is **divide the content into 3 tables to make it tool like one**,

Comment: @SahilPatel yeah if the pure css doesn't work then we have to go with 3 tables.

Comment: @NikhilNanjappa yeah currect