# html table horizontal scroll enabling for specific columns

Tags: javascript, html, css

Lets consider the following image. I am generating a monthly report of working duration of employees.. when the horizontal scrollbar is moved to the right, i want the `code,name, area, territory` column to be fixed on its position and the date columns should be horizontally scrollable. When scrolling right, the date columns should go underneath the `code,name, area, territory` column groups. How can i do it? Is there any css tricks or plugins available?

[image: Example Table]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTML table with horizontal scrolling (first column fixed)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3402295/html-table-with-horizontal-scrolling-first-column-fixed)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the most simple and logical way to fix columns according to @Circuit Breaker [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53526213/5386059) is

```css
.view {
  margin: auto;
  width: 600px;
}

.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  overflow: auto;
  border: 1px solid black;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.sticky-col {
  position: sticky;
  position: -webkit-sticky;    
  background-color: white;
}

.first-col {
  width: 100px;
  min-width: 100px;
  max-width: 100px;
  left: 0px;    
}

.second-col {
  width: 150px;
  min-width: 150px;
  max-width: 150px;
  left: 100px;    
}
```

```html
<div class="view">
  <div class="wrapper"> 
    <table class="table">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th class="sticky-col first-col">Number</th>
          <th class="sticky-col second-col">First Name</th>
          <th>Last Name</th>
          <th>Employer</th>
       </tr>
      </thead>
       <tbody>
       <tr>
         <td class="sticky-col first-col">1</td>
         <td class="sticky-col second-col">Mark</td>
         <td>Ham</td>
         <td>Micro</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <td class="sticky-col first-col">2</td>
         <td class="sticky-col second-col">Jacob</td>
         <td>Smith</td>
         <td>Adob Adob Adob AdobAdob Adob Adob Adob Adob</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <td class="sticky-col first-col">3</td>
         <td class="sticky-col second-col">Larry</td>
         <td>Wen</td>
         <td>Goog Goog Goog GoogGoog Goog Goog Goog Goog Goog</td>
       </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: this is the best solution i have found on  stackoverflow.

Comment: This is the best solution I have found on the entire web!