# How to stop scrolling on some part of table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a table in my page like following:

```
<div style="overflow-x: scroll; width:300px;">
<table>
   <tr>
   <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
   <td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Now the table is scrolling in x direction. but i want to prevent the first and second column to scrolling. Please help

Comment: have you considered using to tables in line? one of which is non-scrollable the other one is?

Comment: duplicate : 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1312236/how-do-i-create-an-html-table-with-fixed-frozen-left-column-and-scrollable-body