# Make first column fixed and rest scrollable in a table

Tags: jquery, html, css

In my table I want to freeze the first column and make other columns scrollable if the td overflows.

I tried here in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZswNc/17/) but it's not working as expected.

there can be 100 rows.

I need first column is fixed and the part that has other columns is scrollable but individual td will remain fixed –
thanks in advance

Comment: a div can't be a child of a table

Comment: You may want to have a look at this question

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1312236/how-do-i-create-an-html-table-with-fixed-frozen-left-column-and-scrollable-body

Comment: I need first column is fixed and the part that has other td's is scrollable but individual td will remain fixed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although not perfect and depending on your use case and how you generate your HTML you can do something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/ZswNc/19/).

**HTML**

```
<table id="main">
    <tr>
        <td class="first"> what are the possible values?</td>
        <td rowspan="2">
            <div class="rest">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>100</td>
                    <td>200</td>
                    <td>300</td>
                    <td>400</td>
                    <td>500</td>
                    <td>600</td>
                    <td>700</td>
                    <td>800</td>
                    <td>900</td>
                    <td>1000</td>
                    <td>1100</td>
                </tr>                        
                <tr>
                    <td>100</td>
                    <td>200</td>
                    <td>300</td>
                    <td>400</td>
                    <td>500</td>
                    <td>600</td>
                    <td>700</td>
                    <td>800</td>
                    <td>900</td>
                    <td>1000</td>
                    <td>1100</td>
                </tr>                        
                </table>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="first_column">
        <td class="first"> what are the possible values?</td>
    </tr>
</table>​
```

**CSS**

```
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
table#main {
    border-top: 1px solid #DFDFDF;
    margin-bottom: 1em;
    width:400px;
    display: block;
}
table#main .first {
    width:200px;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
table#main .rest {
    overflow: scroll;
    background: silver;
    width:200px;
}
table td.first, table .rest td {
    line-height: 1.5em;
    padding: 0.5em 0.6em;
    text-align: left;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: left;
}
```

​**PS** I only tested this on Safari 6 and Firefox 12, 13 & 14 on OSX
​

Comment: Looks interesting.. but i need in different way.. there can be 100 rows... only the first column of 100 row should be freezed. rest part (which has remaining columns) should be scrollable...

Comment: @Maaz My example does that (again only tested in Safari 6, so you may need to tweak it)? The left/first column is fixed the rest can be scrolled left and right. Is it not working for you?

Comment: @Maaz Updated the JSFiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/ZswNc/19/) How do you generate your HTML btw? You can generate a table like this on the server of change a regular table from the server into this suggested structure on the client using JavaScript.

Comment: @Maaz Happy with my answer? Would you like to approve my answer?

Comment: I realise this entry is pretty old, but I was looking for a solution to this and came across.  My contribution is just to add some jQuery to change the height of the first column.  The above won't work if you have dynamic content which changes the height of the rows.  See [http://jsfiddle.net/ZswNc/131/](http://jsfiddle.net/ZswNc/131/).