# table with fixed first header and fixed column

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need to stress that this is about HORIZONTAL scrolling with THE FIRST COLUMN FIXED because most answers are giving me solutions to vertical scrolling.

Is it possible using pure css to have a table that scrolls horizontally but the first header and first column are fixed with the rest of the content scrollable?

For example if I had this table:

```
<table>
  <thead>
   <tr>
     <th class="head1">Head 1</th>
     <th class="head2">Head 2</th>
     <th class="head2">Head 3</th>
   </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
   <tr>
     <td class="col1">Col 1</td>
     <td class="col2">Col 2</td>
     <td class="col3">Col 3</td>
   </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

The head1 and col1 would always be shown with the other columns scrollable.

Comment: Already answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17067294/html-table-with-100-width-with-vertical-scroll-inside-tbody

Comment: This answered might help you as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17827908/how-to-make-fixed-header-table-inside-scrollable-div

Comment: I am asking for a fixed first column with horizontal scrolling so neither of those links are relevant.

Comment: @Adriansyah you are completely wrong and did not read the question and also marked me down without reading the question.  I am looking for a fixed first column with horizontal scrolling and not vertical scrolling.

Comment: @Aragon0 same comment as above goes to you

Comment: Perhaps this one is more on point: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20086473/table-with-fixed-and-scrolling-columns

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan that is the same as the above.  I am talking about horizontal scrolling

Comment: Have a look at this (with jQuery, but it doesn't seem to be possible without JS): http://jsfiddle.net/C8Dtf/81/

Comment: @dagda1, Actually, it is a different question, with the title "Table with fixed and scrolling columns", which seems to be on point. Please follow the link.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan it is not on point

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This](http://jsfiddle.net/GnN66/2/) is what I was after.  The example uses 2 tables that are floated left with an overflow applied to a div that wraps the right most table.  Both tables are contained in a div with a fixed width.

```
<div class="table-container">
  <div class="left">
    <table>
      ...
    </table>
   </div>
  <div class="right">
    <table>
      ...
    </table>
   </div>
</div>

.table-container {
    position: relative;
    width: 600px;
    height: 100%;    
    display: inline-block;
}
table {
    float: left;
}

.right {
    overflow: auto;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<table >
   <tr>
      <th>abc</th>
      <th>xyz</th>
   </tr>

 <tr>
    <td colspan="2">
        <div  style="height:50px; overflow:scroll;">
           <table>
                <tr>
                  <td>1</td>
                  <td>1</td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                  <td>2</td>
                  <td>2</td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                  <td>3</td>
                  <td>3</td>
                </tr> 
          </table>
       </div>
     </td>
   </tr>
  </table>
```

Please check it. It may be work.

Comment: The question adds for horizontal scrolling not vertical with the first column fixed.

Comment: You have to use overflow-x:scroll property for horizontal scrolling

Comment: I am looking for a fixed first column but I must have worded the question wrong because everybody has given me answers for vertical scrolling without any mention of a fixed first column.