# Fix column in table twitter bootstrap

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm have a table, which becomes scroll-able if the screen size is to small to comfortably view the whole table (`table-responsive`). However, there is one column in my table, I'd like to stay fixed. It is always the same column I need fixed (the second - in my example: "Student"), but the 'Student' cells for each table is not necessarily the same width. I have several tables on the site, which sometimes are hidden (only one is shown at a time - see example). Would this be possible to do?

Example (To scroll be sure that the window is less than 800px wide):

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8nXvf/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is possible, but it's not exactly trivial to do. In a nutshell, you need to add a new class to each of the column headers/cells (as with a table layout, they are not grouped by column). Then you need to add some CSS for this class to set the position to absolute, along with a few other tweaks (widths, etc).

[Here is a prior StackOverflow question/answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1312236/how-do-i-create-an-html-table-with-fixed-frozen-left-column-and-scrollable-body)