# iOS 7 absolute postion inside table-responsive not working

Tags: ios, css, twitter-bootstrap, webkit

I fixated the two first left columns in my tables based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/17557830/1272712. The columns is only fixated, when the screen size is less than 768px - at which point the table is scrollable (see [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/98hk3/)). It works great on Android, desktop Chrome and desktop Safari, but it doesn't work on iOS Safari and Chrome. Does iOS not support `position:absolute`?

If anybody else have any alternative implementations, I'll accept that as an answer.

http://jsfiddle.net/98hk3/

Comment: TD/TH elements doesn't approve position properties (relative/absolute/fixed). You might get away in some browsers, but it should not be done like this.

Comment: There is a known bug in firefox that I think may be related to this: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=63895

Comment: take a look at this, it may help. http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/mobile-web-apps/ios-5-fixed-positioning-and-content-scrolling/

Comment: try this, maybe work for you
min-width: 100%;
width: 768px;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have stuck in min-width problem,

I will say that its simple to solve this in case you will convert pixel to em,

if you base size is 16px (by default it is same in all browsers)

then your PX to Em will be (px)768 / 16 = 48(em)

Now try changing Px to Em in the code  [`Fiddle 0`](http://jsfiddle.net/MarmeeK/YWQRU/4/)

also if you must stay with PX, then do something like this,

@media(max-width:768px !important)

[`fiddle 1`](http://jsfiddle.net/MarmeeK/YWQRU/1/)
or

@media(max-width:99%)
[`Fiddle 2`](http://jsfiddle.net/MarmeeK/YWQRU/2/)

Note:I suggest we keep 1 or 2 % spare(by applying 99%) because if we have applied padding some where within body that will create overflow to top level.

Also try adding `zoom:1;` under `.table-responsive` class that might help in case of iOS [`fiddle 3`](http://jsfiddle.net/MarmeeK/YWQRU/3/)

if this does not work out please reply..

Comment: ok I will do one thing will try this on agent/simulator as I do not have a real one to test the same..

Comment: I will like to ask one more thing, is table a compulsory part of the same? or optional part?

Comment: I ned the styles of the bootstrap tables and the ability to shrink my table according to the screen size (`table-responsive`)

Comment: That can be achieved using Div only, so if you can skip/avoid table part and convert same to div tags that will help you to overcome this problem. I can create one fiddle if you want then.(as I am running bit busy).

Comment: I would love a fiddle with that option. I'll award you the bounty, as you have provided me with much more help than any other :)

Comment: Thank you for your kindness, I was closely monitoring your code before converting it to Div format I have one more fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/MarmeeK/YWQRU/8/ that I will like you to test, as there were afew tags `<td />` that are self-closing `td` tags and are not supported by all browsers, So I changed them back to normal `<td></td>`.

Comment: you tried the new fiddle link? Ok I will start buiding the Div pattern, that will carry width of each cell, so the css part is going to change mainly

Comment: FYI it will take more time as there are <td> with colspan, so things are not going to be easy for me too :)

Answer (score 2):

I was able to get this working by overriding the `-webkit-overflow-scrolling` property to be `unset`.

I believe it defaults to `touch` in iOS which for some reason was throwing off the `position:absolute` I was trying to set.