# HTML Table Horizontal and Vertical Scrolling while left column is fixed

Tags: html, css, scroll, html-table

I'm trying to create an `HTML` table where its **height is limited** and the left side stays fixed while scrolling horizontally (and the table body is scrollable horizontally) but not fixed while scrolling vertically (the left side will be scrollable with the rest of the table).

```
fixed    scrollable
  1     body content
  2     body content
  3     body content
  4     body content
  .          .
  .          .
  .          .
```

I found [**this solution**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1312236/how-do-i-create-an-html-table-with-fixed-frozen-left-column-and-scrollable-body), but it only addresses horizontal scrolling. In *Eamon Nerbonne* **[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/emn13/YMvk9/)** example, adding a `height: 150px;` to the div will demonstrate the bug I'm trying to solve.

Is it possible to achieve it only using HTML and CSS?

Comment: Why would want the table to scroll vertically while the first column is fixed? wouldn't you be breaking the rows this way?

Comment: @myajouri Think about adding to the stack overflow's code box (table) a fixed td with row's numbers (1,2,3..). I want the row numbers to be fixed while the rest of the body is scrollable.

Comment: But the line numbers scroll vertically with the rest of the box, don't they? lines would have wrong numbers otherwise.

Comment: Do you want a vertical scroll with the fixed first column as well?

Comment: @LearningByCoding I want the left td to be fixed while scrolling horizontally BUT not fixed while scrolling vertically (assuming table height is limited/fixed).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Adding another div to the Eamon Nerbonne's [solution](http://jsfiddle.net/emn13/YMvk9/), gave me the following solution:

[**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/4kpzN/)

Basically the solution is, if you add another parent div that controls the flow of the secondary div might give you a go.

```
<div class="first">
    <div class="second">
        <table>
            <tr><td class="headcol">1</td><td class="long">QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM</td><td class="long">QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM</td></tr>
            <tr><td class="headcol">2</td><td class="long">QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM</td><td class="long">QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM</td></tr>
            <tr><td class="headcol">3</td><td class="long">QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM</td><td class="long">QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM</td></tr>
            <tr><td class="headcol">4</td><td class="long">QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM</td><td class="long">QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM</td></tr>
            <tr><td class="headcol">5</td><td class="long">QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM</td><td class="long">QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM</td></tr>
            <tr><td class="headcol">6</td><td class="long">QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM</td><td class="long">QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM</td></tr>
            <tr><td class="headcol">7</td><td class="long">QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM</td><td class="long">QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM</td></tr>
            <tr><td class="headcol">8</td><td class="long">QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM</td><td class="long">QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM</td></tr>
            <tr><td class="headcol">9</td><td class="long">QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM</td><td class="long">QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM</td></tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

I added style for the outer div like this:

```
div.first {
    width: auto;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    height: 150px;     /* this is the height that you expect to contain */      
    padding-bottom: 1px;
    position: absolute;
    left:0;
    top:auto;
}
```

Comment: I want to add scroll bar after each individual tr and not for the table as a whole......what changes should I make?

Comment: @NikitaDhiman You want each row with scroll with the first column fixed? Why don't you use a div inside each `tr`>`td`

Answer (score 2):

A little late but I did run across this thread when trying out solutions for myself. Assuming you're using modern browsers nowadays, I came up with a solution using CSS calc() to help guarantee widths met up.

```css
.table-fixed-left table,
.table-fixed-right table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
.table-fixed-right td,
.table-fixed-right th,
.table-fixed-left td,
.table-fixed-left th {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  padding: 5px 5px;
}
.table-fixed-left {
  width: 120px;
  float: left;
  position: fixed;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-align: left;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  z-index: 2;
}
.table-fixed-right {
  width: calc(100% - 145px);
  right: 15px;
  position: fixed;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.table-fixed-right td,
.table-fixed-right th {
  padding: 5px 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="table-fixed-left">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>Normal Header</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Header with extra line
        <br/>&nbsp;</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Normal Header</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Normal with extra line
        <br/>&nbsp;</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Normal Header</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Normal Header</th>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
<div class="table-fixed-right">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>Header</th>
      <th>Another header</th>
      <th>Header</th>
      <th>Header really really really really long</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Info Long</td>
      <td>Info
        <br/>with second line</td>
      <td>Info
        <br/>with second line</td>
      <td>Info Long</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Info Long</td>
      <td>Info Long</td>
      <td>Info Long</td>
      <td>Info Long</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Info
        <br/>with second line</td>
      <td>Info
        <br/>with second line</td>
      <td>Info
        <br/>with second line</td>
      <td>Info</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Info</td>
      <td>Info</td>
      <td>Info</td>
      <td>Info</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Info</td>
      <td>Info</td>
      <td>Info</td>
      <td>Info</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Hope this helps anyone!