# Always show horizontal scroll in visible area of table

Tags: html, css

I have a table where I would like the left hand column to be fixed when scrolling horizontally `only`.

I found a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20869642/scroll-html-table-horizontal-and-vertical-while-left-column-is-fixed) which covers almost exactly what I am after as per this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4kpzN/)

The only downside is that to see the horizontal scroll you have to vertically scroll to the bottom of the table. Is there a way to get the horizontal scroll to appear immediately inside the visible scrollable area? I hope that makes some sort of sense!?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, so I used trick with `position: sticky` for first column's cells combined with `display: flex` with for `tr`.

```
tr {
  display: flex;
}

tr > td:first-of-type {
  position: sticky;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  background: red;
}
```

=> [Codepen](https://codepen.io/ajzk/pen/wXYeMG).

Comment: This doesnt work as the first column of cells needs to be sticky

Comment: this actually breaks it and causes the first column to scrolll, whereas the question was how to keep it from scrolling.

Comment: I have an idea. Can you alter HTML structure, or it has to be just CSS?

Comment: Im open to any suggestions! Yes I can alter HTML no problem

Comment: [I have updated my Codepen](https://codepen.io/ajzk/pen/wXYeMG). Could you please check it now and let me know if it's OK for you?

Answer (score 3):

You can use [floating-scroll](https://github.com/Amphiluke/floating-scroll) plugin.
[NPM](https://www.npmjs.com/package/floating-scroll), [Demo](https://amphiluke.github.io/floating-scroll/)

Comment: You don't need any plugins. [Pure CSS solution is possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51059423/always-show-horizontal-scroll-in-visible-area-of-table/51059606#51059606).

Comment: @AndrzejZiółek your CSS solution is great but there is one caveat. If the viewport height is smaller than table you will not see the bottom scrollbar unless you scroll to this scrollbar.

Therefore, mindparse should choose proper solution depending on his needs.

Comment: _ If the viewport height is smaller than table you will not see the bottom scrollbar_ -- you will, if you set height properly. Depends on developer's needs.