# Scroll HTML table horizontally and vertically while left column is fixed and header is fixed for vertical scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

[Scroll HTML table horizontal and vertical while left column is fixed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20869642/scroll-html-table-horizontal-and-vertical-while-left-column-is-fixed)

From the above thread I am able to scroll an HTML table horizontally and vertically while the left column is fixed but I want to fix the vertical scrolling of the header.

The HTML table that I'd like to have:

- vertical scrolling
- horizontal scrolling
- fixed headers (that do not support vertical scrolling, but horizontal scrolling)
- Fixed left column

I have used a Jquery DataTable which is working great but I also want to hide and show some of the columns. But this jQuery Datatable has a performance issue if we have too many rows and too many columns (which we want hide and show).

**Can we solve this problem using HTML, CSS, jQuery and Javascript**

Could any one please help me on this?

Answer (score 0):

you can you the below code

```
$(document).ready( function () {
$('#myTable').DataTable( {
    fixedHeader: true
} );
} );
```

And can download the related files from
https://github.com/DataTables/FixedHeader

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. As i mentioned in the thread, I don't want to use the jQuery Datatable because I also want to hide and show some of the columns but jQuery Datatable has a performance issue if we have too many rows and too many columns (which we want hide and show). Can we do solve this issue with out Datatable?