# Make tds scrollable but leave th where it is?

Tags: css, html-table

Let's say this is the table:

```
<table>
    <tbody>
         <tr>
             <th>something goes here</th>
             <td>dkjfkldfjlfjs</td> 
             <td>dkjfkldfjlfjs 4234324</td>
             <td>dkjfkldfjlfjfdgfdggs</td>
         </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Is it somehow possible to only scroll the tds from from left to right but leave the th where it is? Like when you fix a column in Excel where only the first column (the th) is frozen and the rest (all tds) scrolls at once.

Comment: http://salzerdesign.com/blog/?p=191

Comment: here you can find some ideas : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1312236/how-do-i-create-an-html-table-with-fixed-frozen-left-column-and-scrollable-body

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can, just apply `overflow-x:scroll;` with a `display:inline-block;` to achieve what you are looking for.

**[WORKING DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/VpA2W/)**

**The CSS:**

```
td {
    display: inline-block;
    overflow-x: scroll;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: @NathanLee : he want to freeze first column of table. Are u on the same path ?

Comment: Its not exactly what I meant ... I wanted all the tds to scroll at once. I guess this is not possible? I updated my question.

Comment: Three `td's` can't scroll at once. Give me a graphic or an existing link of an example of how you want - @user1856596

Comment: Yes, he wants a freeze column, but he has specifically mentioned to use scrolls on `td's` - @Era

Comment: @user1856596 you can add scroll to tbody instead of td

Answer (score 0):

Fiddle demo : [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/VpA2W/13/)

When apply scroll to tbody, it may collapse table design. you have to manually apply width on header.

Adding scroll div block, below css is enough

```
min-height:200px;
overflow:auto;
```

For more details please check this [blog post](http://chillydraji.wordpress.com/tag/scrollbar/)