# Two fixed column table

Tags: html, css, html-table

I am trying to create a two fixed column table (freeze the first two columns), that respects the widths of the td elements that I give them.

When the two columns get fixed, the widths of the columns are randomly set.

```
<div id="tableContainer">
<table class="all-table">
                    <colgroup>
                    <col  style="width:30px;" />
                    <col  style="width:30px;" />
                    <col style="width:180px;" />
                    <col style="width:180px;" />
                    <col style="width:180px;" />
                    <col style="width:30px;" />
                </colgroup>
<thead>
<tr>
    <td class="td-fixed gray-background">a</td>
    <td class="td-fixed td-fixed-margin gray-background">a</td>
    <td class="gray-background">aaaaaaaaaaaa</td>
    ...
</tr>
    ...
    </thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
    <td class="td-fixed white-background">a</td>
    <td class="td-fixed td-fixed-margin white-background" >a</td>
    <td>aaaaaaaaaaaa</td>
    ...
    </tr>
        <tr>
    <td class="td-fixed white-background">a</td>
    <td class="td-fixed td-fixed-margin white-background">a</td>
    <td >aaaaaaaaaaaa</td>
    ...
</tr>
    ...
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

The CSS part can be found in the link.

http://jsfiddle.net/pcmhd42e/8/

http://jsfiddle.net/pcmhd42e/9/ - updated version from gewh

Could not find a workaround that would work with CSS, the solution does not use Bootstrap.

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure about the correct method to do it, but this might help.

```css
#tableContainer {
  width: 300px;
  overflow: auto;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
.td-fixed {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0px;
  width: 30px;
  z-index: 1;
  height: 25px;
}
.white-background {
  background-color: white;
}
.gray-background {
  background-color: gray;
}
.td-fixed-margin {
  margin-left: 31px;
}
.td-fixed-padding {
  padding-left: 31px;
}
.all-table {
  width: 300px;
  margin-top: 0;
  table-layout: fixed;
  border-spacing: 0;
}
td {
  border-right: solid 1px #cccccc;
  border-bottom: solid 1px #cccccc;
  height: 25px;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  -ms-text-overflow: ellipsis;
  -o-text-overflow: ellipsis;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
.td-editable-position {
  left: 148px;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div id="tableContainer">
  <table class="all-table">
    <colgroup>
      <col style="width:54px;" />
      <col style="width:180px;" />
      <col style="width:180px;" />
      <col style="width:180px;" />
      <col style="width:30px;" />
    </colgroup>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <td class="td-fixed gray-background">a</td>
        <td class="td-fixed td-fixed-margin gray-background">a</td>
        <td class="gray-background">aaaaaaaaaaaa</td>
        <td class="gray-background">aaaaaaaaaaaa</td>
        <td class="gray-background">aaaaaaaaaaaa</td>
        <td class="gray-background">aaaaaaaaaaaa</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="td-fixed gray-background">a</td>
        <td class="td-fixed td-fixed-margin gray-background">a</td>
        <td class="gray-background">aaaaaaaaaaaa</td>
        <td class="gray-background">aaaaaaaaaaaa</td>
        <td class="gray-background">aaaaaaaaaaaa</td>
        <td class="gray-background">aaaaaaaaaaaa</td>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td class="td-fixed white-background">a</td>
        <td class="td-fixed td-fixed-margin white-background">a</td>
        <td>aaaaaaaaaaaa</td>
        <td>aaaaaaaaaaaa</td>
        <td>aaaaaaaaaaaa</td>
        <td>aaaaaaaaaaaa</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="td-fixed white-background">a</td>
        <td class="td-fixed td-fixed-margin white-background">a</td>
        <td>aaaaaaaaaaaa</td>
        <td>aaaaaaaaaaaa</td>
        <td>aaaaaaaaaaaa</td>
        <td>aaaaaaaaaaaa</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="td-fixed white-background">a</td>
        <td class="td-fixed td-fixed-margin white-background">a</td>
        <td>aaaaaaaaaaaa</td>
        <td>aaaaaaaaaaaa</td>
        <td>aaaaaaaaaaaa</td>
        <td>aaaaaaaaaaaa</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="td-fixed white-background">a</td>
        <td class="td-fixed td-fixed-margin white-background">a</td>
        <td>aaaaaaaaaaaa</td>
        <td>aaaaaaaaaaaa</td>
        <td>aaaaaaaaaaaa</td>
        <td>aaaaaaaaaaaa</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="td-fixed white-background">a</td>
        <td class="td-fixed td-fixed-margin white-background">a</td>
        <td>aaaaaaaaaaaa</td>
        <td>aaaaaaaaaaaa</td>
        <td>aaaaaaaaaaaa</td>
        <td>aaaaaaaaaaaa</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

When using the `position` rule in CSS, `top` `left` `right` and `bottom` values are the method of positioning these elements.

[I hope this updated fiddle is more what you are after?](http://jsfiddle.net/pcmhd42e/9/)

Comment: Yes, thanks, but the other column that are not fixed, still don't get the desired width. I am mainly stuck in that part.

Comment: Perils of the early morning. I see now this doesn't fix your problem at all. It also didn't require the `left` rule I put in, only `width`. It is entirely down to the `colgroup` not working as intended because two of the columns have indeed been taken out of the flow position and into fixed position. [This looks like it might be of use for you](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1312236/how-do-i-create-an-html-table-with-fixed-frozen-left-column-and-scrollable-body) and then applying the width in CSS rather than using `<colgroup>`?

Answer (score 0):

if you are using jQuery I would recommend using [Sticky Table](https://github.com/armaaar/JQuery-Sticky-Table) plugin. You only need to use their classes to do what you want without changing your code structure or add any crappy JS code.

Answer (score 0):

This code below worked for me. 5 columns btw. You just need to adjust the `left` pixels in the five fixed columns (`first` to `fifth`) to your needs.

```css
.view {
    width: fit-content;
    overflow-x: initial;
}

.wrapper {
    position: relative;
    white-space: nowrap;
    padding: 0px;
}

.sticky-col {
    position: sticky;
    /* border: 1px solid red !important; */
    position: -webkit-sticky;
    background-color: white !important;
    text-align: center;
}

.first-col {
    width: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    left: 0px;
}

.second-col {
    width: 50px;
    left: 50px;
}

.third-col {
    width: 50px;
    left: 100px;
}

.fourth-col {
    width: 50px;
    left: 147px;
}

.fifth-col {
    width: 150px;
    left: 200px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.0.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="row view">
  <div class="col-md-12 wrapper">
    <table class="table" id="tabelaListaProduto">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th class="sticky-col first-col">Column 1</th>
          <th class="sticky-col second-col">Column 2</th>
          <th class="sticky-col third-col">Column 3</th>
          <th class="sticky-col fourth-col">Column 4</th>
          <th class="sticky-col fifth-col">Description</th>
          <th>Brand</th>
          <th>Packing</th>
          <th>Image</th>
          <th>Image</th>
          <th>Image</th>
          <th>Image</th>
          <th>Image</th>
          <th>Image</th>
          <th>Image</th>
          <th>Image</th>
          <th>Image</th>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td class="sticky-col first-col">Lorem</i></td>
          <td class="sticky-col second-col ">Ipsum</td>
          <td class="sticky-col third-col">Dolor</td>
          <td class="sticky-col fourth-col">Amet</td>
          <td class="sticky-col fifth-col">Sitcom</td>
          <td>MULTILASER</td>
          <td>CX</td>
          <td>ABCABC</td>
          <td>ABCABC</td>
          <td>ABCABC</td>
          <td>ABCABC</td>
          <td>ABCABC</td>
          <td>ABCABC</td>
          <td>ABCABC</td>
          <td>ABCABC</td>
          <td>ABCABC</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="sticky-col first-col">Lorem</i></td>
          <td class="sticky-col second-col ">Ipsum</td>
          <td class="sticky-col third-col">Dolor</td>
          <td class="sticky-col fourth-col">Amet</td>
          <td class="sticky-col fifth-col">Sitcom</td>
          <td>MULTILASER</td>
          <td>CX</td>
          <td>ABCABC</td>
          <td>ABCABC</td>
          <td>ABCABC</td>
          <td>ABCABC</td>
          <td>ABCABC</td>
          <td>ABCABC</td>
          <td>ABCABC</td>
          <td>ABCABC</td>
          <td>ABCABC</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```