# How to make multiple left columns fixed and scroll the the rest columns in HTML table?

Tags: html, css, html-table

I am having trouble of freezing multiple columns or column-group and making the rest columns scrollable.

I tried the solution like

[how do I create an HTML table with fixed/frozen left column and scrollable body?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1312236/how-do-i-create-an-html-table-with-fixed-frozen-left-column-and-scrollable-body)

but it only works for one column. If I try to freeze multiple columns, they overlapped each other.

I also do not want to use multiple tables which will be difficult for dynamic data binding.

Does anyone know a simple solution for this case only using CSS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is one jQuery Plugin "DataTable". This will help you to freeze any number of columns in your table.

Check the tutorials here.
http://www.datatables.net/extensions/fixedcolumns/

http://www.datatables.net/release-datatables/extensions/FixedColumns/examples/two_columns.html

Hope this solves your problem.

Comment: Thanks @Yameen. But my project limited me not to add external plugins anymore. If I could know the solution with CSS only, it would be a great help.