# Fix multiple columns in html table (JQuery)

Tags: javascript, html

I am looking for a way to freeze first three columns in html table. Sample of table: http://jsfiddle.net/ee6reLug/

```
<table>
...
</table>
```

Columns Column name1, "+" and Column name2 must be fixed and scrollable from left to right.

There is a demo for single fixed left column,
[how do I create an HTML table with fixed/frozen left column and scrollable body?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1312236/how-do-i-create-an-html-table-with-fixed-frozen-left-column-and-scrollable-body)

but I need multple columns fixed. Is it possible in html, javascript or jquery?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how do I create an HTML table with fixed/frozen left column and scrollable body?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1312236/how-do-i-create-an-html-table-with-fixed-frozen-left-column-and-scrollable-body)

Comment: Have a look @ this demo http://jsfiddle.net/emn13/YMvk9/

Comment: @AntoKing this demo covers one column freezing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

answering it late.. but useful for someone searching for a solution

I've changed your code to this --> http://jsfiddle.net/PrateekPatra26/ee6reLug/5/

Separated the tables into two, one with 3 columns and the remaining table into another. Put them into div's and gave them specific width.

the css:

```
.pull-left {
    float: left!important
}
.pull-right {
    float: right!important
}
th{
    height:40px;
}
td{
    height:60px;
}
```

div's:

```
<div style="width:100%" class="pull-left">
    <div class='pull-left' style='width:30%'>
       <table>
       .
       .
       .
       </table>
    </div>
    <div class='pull-right' style='width:70%;overflow-x:auto'>
       <table>
       .
       .
       .
       </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Enclose the table in a `div` and set a `margin-left` say 15em. Also set `overflow-x:scroll`

```
.outer { 
   overflow-x:scroll;  
   margin-left:15em; 
   overflow-y:visible;
}
```

Now for the first 3 columns have separate classes and set `position:absolute` and `left` to 0em, 5em and 10em respectively.

```
.headcol1 {
    position:absolute; 
    width:5em;  
   left:0;
   top:auto;
}

.headcol2 {
   position:absolute; 
   width:5em;  
   left:5em;
   top:auto;  
}

.headcol3 {
   position:absolute; 
   width:5em; 
   left:10em;
   top:auto;
}
```

Demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ee6reLug/1/)

PS: I have some problems setting the column heights. If someone could fix that it will be helpful.