# Creating HTML table with sticky headers and columns using only CSS

Tags: css, google-chrome

I have a table in which I'm trying to make the header, and an arbitrary number of columns on its left "sticky". Sticky as in, as the table data is vertically scrolled, the headers stay stuck to the top. And if there's enough columns to scroll vertically, the data and headers are vertically scrollable, but some columns stick.

Here's a table that's vertically and horizontally scrollable with sticky headers.

http://jsfiddle.net/7b29Lkwy/5/

The important parts being

```
.sticky-table {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow-x: scroll;
}
.scroll {
    float: left; /* Makes with total content width */
    min-width: 100%; /* In case there isn't enough columns */
    height: calc(100% - 35px); /* Assuming we know head height */
    overflow: scroll;
}
```

But I'm not sure how I can do this while including a sticky column.

Comment: Put the headers in a separate div that doesn't scroll with the rest of it.

Answer (score 0):

You need some js to make it work.

The scrollbars:

```
<button title="Up" onmousedown="upp();" onmouseup="upp(1);">Up</button>
<button title="Left" onmousedown="left();" 
        onmouseup="left(1);">&lt;&lt;</button>
<button title="Right" onmousedown="right();" 
        onmouseup="right(1);">&gt;&gt;</button>
<button title="Down" onmousedown="down();" onmouseup="down(1);">Dn</button>
```

Replace t1 with your table ID

```
if(!myTable){myTable=document.getElementById("t1");
```

And of course the working js

```
var myRow=1;
  var myCol=1;
  var myTable;
  var noRows;
  var myCells,ID;

function setUp(){
    if(!myTable){myTable=document.getElementById("t1");}
     myCells = myTable.rows[0].cells.length;
    noRows=myTable.rows.length;

    for( var x = 0; x < myTable.rows[0].cells.length; x++ ) {
        colWdth=myTable.rows[0].cells[x].offsetWidth;
        myTable.rows[0].cells[x].setAttribute("width",colWdth-4);

    } 
}

function right(up){
    if(up){window.clearTimeout(ID);return;}
    if(!myTable){setUp();}

    if(myCol<(myCells)){
        for( var x = 0; x < noRows; x++ ) {
            myTable.rows[x].cells[myCol].style.display="";
        }
        if(myCol >1){myCol--;}

        ID = window.setTimeout('right()',100);
    }
}

function left(up){
    if(up){window.clearTimeout(ID);return;}
    if(!myTable){setUp();}

    if(myCol<(myCells-1)){
        for( var x = 0; x < noRows; x++ ) {
            myTable.rows[x].cells[myCol].style.display="none";
        }
        myCol++
        ID = window.setTimeout('left()',100);

    }
}

function down(up){
    if(up){window.clearTimeout(ID);return;}
    if(!myTable){setUp();}

    if(myRow<(noRows-1)){
            myTable.rows[myRow].style.display="none";
            myRow++    ;

            ID = window.setTimeout('down()',100);
    }    
}

function upp(up){
    if(up){window.clearTimeout(ID);return;}
    if(!myTable){setUp();}

    if(myRow<=noRows){
        myTable.rows[myRow].style.display="";
        if(myRow >1){myRow--;}
        ID = window.setTimeout('upp()',100);
    }    
}
```

Refer here for the detailed explanation
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20017/Freeze-Panes-like-Excel

**Update:**
Solution to problem is to use this jquery table plugin ->
[jtable](http://meetselva.github.io/fixed-table-rows-cols/)

Comment: I would prefer to support native scrolling and scrollbars.

Comment: This [another SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1312236/how-do-i-create-an-html-table-with-fixed-frozen-left-column-and-scrollable-body) ?

Comment: That has a fixed column but no header. I'm looking to do both. It seems I can only find solutions for one but not both.

Comment: [jtable](http://meetselva.github.io/fixed-table-rows-cols/)

Jquery table plugin?

Comment: That might work. Although I notice some errors on their examples. I'll follow development for it, thanks!

Comment: No problem :) i just mod the answer so other people can also see.