# Scrollable table, locked first column with CSS, Joomla

Tags: html, css, joomla, scrollable

I know that there some extensions that can make this happen but I want to do it this way (if possible). I have tried several methods with "child" and nowrap command but can't get it to work. I have made table and everything is fine. However I want it to be more advanced on mobile devices and to lock the first column on place -> everything else should scroll left. How it could be done with only HTML and CSS (NO Javascript). I have theme.css with CSS code, and will make Custom HTML code module for the page with table itself.

```css
.table-container{
    overflow-y: scroll;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}
@media screen and (min-width: 900px){
    .table-container {
       overflow: visible;
    }
}

.table-container body{
    padding: 1em;
    font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    color: #222;
}
.table-container table{
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
    background-color: white;
    width: 100%;
    border: 0px solid #620376;
}
.table-container th, td{
    padding: 0.25em 0.75em;
    text-align: left;
}
.table-container th{
    background-color: #000000;
    white-space: nowrap;
   color: white;
}
.table-container td{
    border-top: 1px solid #000000;
}
tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #929292;
}
```

```html
<div class="table-container">
   <table class="data-table">
      <thead>
         <tr>
            <th> </th>
            <th> </th>
            <th><center>Parameter S</center></th>
            <th><center>Parameter S</center></th>
            <th><center>Parameter S</center></th>
            <th><center>Parameter S</center></th>
         </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
         <tr>
            <td>Parameter 1</td>
            <td><center>m2</center></td>
            <td><center>m2</center></td>
            <td><center>m2</center></td>
                <td><center>m2</center></td>
                <td><center>m2</center></td>
         </tr>   
         <tr>
            <td>Parameter 2</td>
            <td><center>m2</center></td>
            <td><center>m2</center></td>
            <td><center>m2</center></td>
                <td><center>m2</center></td>
                <td><center>m2</center></td>
         </tr>   
            <tr>
            <td>Parameter 3</td>
            <td><center>m2</center></td>
            <td><center>m2</center></td>
            <td><center>m2</center></td>
                <td><center>m2</center></td>
                <td><center>m2</center></td>
         </tr>   
            <tr>
            <td>Parameter 3</td>
            <td><center>m2</center></td>
            <td><center>m2</center></td>
            <td><center>m2</center></td>
                <td><center>m2</center></td>
                <td><center>m2</center></td>
         </tr>   
            <tr>
            <td>Parameter 4</td>
            <td><center>m2</center></td>
            <td><center>m2</center></td>
            <td><center>m2</center></td>
                <td><center>m2</center></td>
                <td><center>m2</center></td>
         </tr>   
                        <tr>
            <td>Parameter 5</td>
            <td><center>m2</center></td>
            <td><center>m2</center></td>
            <td><center>m2</center></td>
                <td><center>m2</center></td>
                <td><center>m2</center></td>
         </tr>
                        <tr>
            <td>Parameter 6</td>
            <td><center>m2</center></td>
            <td><center>m2</center></td>
            <td><center>m2</center></td>
                <td><center>m2</center></td>
                <td><center>m2</center></td>
         </tr>
                        <tr>
            <td>Parameter 7</td>
            <td><center>m2</center></td>
            <td><center>m2</center></td>
            <td><center>m2</center></td>
                <td><center>m2</center></td>
                <td><center>m2</center></td>
         </tr>
                        <tr>
            <td>Parameter 8</td>
            <td><center>m2</center></td>
            <td><center>m2</center></td>
            <td><center>m2</center></td>
                <td><center>m2</center></td>
                <td><center>m2</center></td>
         </tr>
      </tbody>
   </table>
</div>
```

Comment: *No javascript* **Why do you tag it??**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is commonly referred to as "freezing" or "locking".  A quick search on SO turned up [how do I create an HTML table with fixed/frozen left column and scrollable body?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1312236/how-do-i-create-an-html-table-with-fixed-frozen-left-column-and-scrollable-body) which should help you.  The key is making the first column fixed width and position it absolute.  Start by just trying out the .headcol class referenced in that post and see what you get.  You can remove a lot of the styling he has in there to suit your needs.