# How to freeze first column and header in this html table?

Tags: html, css

I have made two separate divs. The first div contains the name of projects and second div contains the different metrics and their scores for each project.
I want to keep first div fixed and vertical scrollable . and second div horizontal scrollable. But i am not able to achieve the same. Any insight is deeply appreciated. 
[Here's my fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lt7aP/4201/)

I am using

```
   display: inline-block;
background-color: white;
width: 50%;
height: calc(100% - 72px);
position: absolute;
overflow-x: scroll;
overflow-y: hidden;
```

this class to get horizontal scroll on second div but not getting any.

Comment: i'd start by looking here, this should help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1312236/how-do-i-create-an-html-table-with-fixed-frozen-left-column-and-scrollable-body

Comment: Look into flexbox. Create two wrappers and then content elements in them with the scrolling you need.

Comment: Can you please give name or Id and then use that instead of first and second div? not sure which one is required..

Comment: i got two divs: name table div and metric table div. I want vertical scroll on both divs at the same time and i need horizontal scroll on metric table div. Exactly like this : http://jsfiddle.net/fw0od1bh/10/ . But this fiddle table doesnot fit to viewport screen