# Second column in HTML table is behind the (fixed) first one

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have a problem with my HTML table... I am trying to have a scrollbar when my table is too wide for the page. I'd like the first column to remain fixed while the user scrolls horizontally. It works but the second column of the table appears behind the first one! It looks like it comes from the `style="position: fixed"` property.

Here's the code:

```html
<table id="coverageMatrix">
      <!-- Table Headings -->
      <tr>
        <th class="center" style="background: #ddd; position: fixed">ertertert</th>
        <th class="center " style="background: #ddd;">azeazeaze</th>
        <th class="center " style="background: #ddd;">azeazeaze</th>
        <th class="center " style="background: #ddd;">azeazeaze</th>
        <th class="center " style="background: #ddd;">azeazeaze</th>
      </tr>
      <tr name="scenarioRaws">
        <th style="position: fixed">qsdqsd</th>
        <td>toto</td>
        <td>toto</td>
        <td>toto</td>
        <td>toto</td>
      </tr>
      <tr name="scenarioRaws">
        <th style="position: fixed">qsdqsd</th>
        <td>toto</td>
        <td>toto</td>
        <td>toto</td>
        <td>toto</td>
      </tr>
      <tr name="scenarioRaws">
        <th style="position: fixed">qsdqsd</th>
        <td>toto</td>
        <td>toto</td>
        <td>toto</td>
        <td>toto</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: This is how it should behave

Comment: Okay... But how do I get the second column to be after the fixed one and not behind?

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1312236/how-do-i-create-an-html-table-with-fixed-frozen-left-column-and-scrollable-body

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how do I create an HTML table with fixed/frozen left column and scrollable body?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1312236/how-do-i-create-an-html-table-with-fixed-frozen-left-column-and-scrollable-body)

Comment: I did check these subjects before posting...

Comment: @Papple you've answered your own question with your comment. If you checked the <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1312236/how-do-i-create-an-html-table-with-fixed-frozen-left-column-and-scrollable-body">this</a> you could see that you're going to need to use CSS to accomplish this. The answer is in the link!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it using [this codepen code](http://codepen.io/ajkochanowicz/pen/KHdih):

```
.fixedTable {
  .table {
    background-color: white;
    width: auto;
    tr { 
      td, th {
        min-width: @cellWidth;
        width: @cellWidth;
        min-height: @cellHeight;
        height: @cellHeight;
        padding: @cellPadding;
      }
    }
  };
  &-header {
    width: (@cellWidth * @cellsWide) + (@cellPadding * 2);
    height: @cellHeight + (@cellPadding * 2);
    margin-left: @cellWidth + (@cellPadding * 2);
    overflow: hidden;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #CCC;
  };
  &-sidebar {
    width: @cellWidth + (@cellPadding * 2);
    height: @cellHeight * @cellsHigh + (@cellPadding * 2);
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
    border-right: 1px solid #CCC;
  };
  &-body {
    overflow: auto;
    width: (@cellWidth * @cellsWide) + (@cellPadding * 2);
    height: (@cellHeight * @cellsHigh) + (@cellPadding * 2);
    float: left;
  }
};
```