# HTML table + fixed columns + position:relative + without default tags for <table>

Tags: html, css, layout

I want to create a specific layout for HTML-tables that has fixed columns WITHOUT using default tags (table, tbody, thead, tr, td, th).

I developed an example that works pretty fine and realized that I need to add `position:relative` to some of the containers. But if I add `position:relative` the layout breaks... See an example below.

So, here is the question. How to create the table with fixed/stuck columns and save `position:relative` as in the example below?

```css
.wrapper {
    overflow-x: scroll;
}

.table, .table-head, .table-row {
  position: relative; /* works perfect WITHOUT this line */
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.table-head .table-cell {
  background: #aaa;
}
.table-cell {
  display: inline-block;
  min-width: 50px;
  border: 1px solid white;
  background: #eee;
}

.fixed {
    position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="content" style="width: 400px">

  <div class="wrapper" style="margin-left: 50px">

      <div class="table">
        <div class="table-head">
          <div class="table-row">
            <div class="table-cell fixed" style="left: 0px">0</div>
            <div class="table-cell">1</div>
            <div class="table-cell">2</div>
            <div class="table-cell">3</div>
            <div class="table-cell">4</div>
            <div class="table-cell">5</div>
            <div class="table-cell">6</div>
            <div class="table-cell">7</div>
            <div class="table-cell">8</div>
            <div class="table-cell">9</div>
            <div class="table-cell">10</div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="table-body">
          <div class="table-row">
              <div class="table-cell fixed" style="left: 0px">a</div>
              <div class="table-cell">b</div>
              <div class="table-cell">c</div>
              <div class="table-cell">d</div>
              <div class="table-cell">e</div>
              <div class="table-cell">f</div>
              <div class="table-cell">a</div>
              <div class="table-cell">b</div>
              <div class="table-cell">c</div>
              <div class="table-cell">d</div>
              <div class="table-cell">e</div> 
          </div>
          <div class="table-row">
              <div class="table-cell fixed" style="left: 0px">a</div>
              <div class="table-cell">b</div>
              <div class="table-cell">c</div>
              <div class="table-cell">d</div>
              <div class="table-cell">e</div>
              <div class="table-cell">f</div>
              <div class="table-cell">a</div>
              <div class="table-cell">b</div>
              <div class="table-cell">c</div>
              <div class="table-cell">d</div>
              <div class="table-cell">e</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

  </div>

</div>
```

I took the inspiration here https://stackoverflow.com/a/42578946/1061438

Comment: But why :-( ???

Comment: @Christoph most of the layout was developed not by me long time ago and the table is being used in plenty of places. The layout you can see above is very simplified ;)

Comment: Why do you need to use `position: relative;` if it works without it? If there is something one the page this table sits in that requires you to add it, can you add that markup as well as it could be in that case that you are trying to fix the layout issues you possibly have when not using it in the wrong place.

Comment: @Fran already partially answered above ^ . I can't omit `position: relative` since I'll definitely break something somewhere. The original table is pretty complicated actually...

Comment: @kashesandr You only said its an existing table used in plenty of places which doesn't show me an exact sample markup that surrounds the table but as I said above and as the below answer addresses, you seem to try and apply the fix in the wrong place. The table should be agnostic to it's usage, so adding a container and applying the logic to the container in the context of it's usage is a better solution as that way your table stays agnostic. If you add the actual markup from one of your scenarios surrounding the table and highlight the issue we can find a solution without guessing.

Comment: @Fran thanks! I think it worth trying another approach... Will keep the topic updated.

Answer (score 2):

What if you change `.fixed` position to `position: fixed` like this?

```css
.wrapper {
    overflow-x: scroll;
}

.table, .table-head, .table-row {
  position: relative; /* works perfect WITHOUT this line */
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.table-head .table-cell {
  background: #aaa;
}
.table-cell {
  display: inline-block;
  min-width: 50px;
  border: 1px solid white;
  background: #eee;
}

.fixed {
    position: fixed;
}
```

```html
<div class="content" style="width: 400px">

  <div class="wrapper" style="margin-left: 50px">

      <div class="table">
        <div class="table-head">
          <div class="table-row">
            <div class="table-cell fixed" style="left: 0px">0</div>
            <div class="table-cell">1</div>
            <div class="table-cell">2</div>
            <div class="table-cell">3</div>
            <div class="table-cell">4</div>
            <div class="table-cell">5</div>
            <div class="table-cell">6</div>
            <div class="table-cell">7</div>
            <div class="table-cell">8</div>
            <div class="table-cell">9</div>
            <div class="table-cell">10</div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="table-body">
          <div class="table-row">
              <div class="table-cell fixed" style="left: 0px">a</div>
              <div class="table-cell">b</div>
              <div class="table-cell">c</div>
              <div class="table-cell">d</div>
              <div class="table-cell">e</div>
              <div class="table-cell">f</div>
              <div class="table-cell">a</div>
              <div class="table-cell">b</div>
              <div class="table-cell">c</div>
              <div class="table-cell">d</div>
              <div class="table-cell">e</div> 
          </div>
          <div class="table-row">
              <div class="table-cell fixed" style="left: 0px">a</div>
              <div class="table-cell">b</div>
              <div class="table-cell">c</div>
              <div class="table-cell">d</div>
              <div class="table-cell">e</div>
              <div class="table-cell">f</div>
              <div class="table-cell">a</div>
              <div class="table-cell">b</div>
              <div class="table-cell">c</div>
              <div class="table-cell">d</div>
              <div class="table-cell">e</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: You forgot to add `.content{position: relative}` in your example but it works either way .

Comment: @TheodoreK. unfortunately it won't work since I can't remove `position: relative; /* works perfect WITHOUT this line */`. it must remain on the place.

Comment: @kashesandr Why can't you remove it? Does it have an impact on how the rest of your page then looks outside your table or is it that you don't have access to that CSS file?

Comment: @TheodoreK. Just found the same , seems `.fixed { position: fixed;}` will also fix it :)

Comment: @Fran, @TheodoreK. hmm I can't believe it does work with just `position:fixed`! Let me try for some time :) looks it should work in different browsers as well.

Comment: Actually, yes it does! Thanks a lot guys!

Comment: Ahh.. I figured out that there are some issues with the solution.. If I put table in container that has `overflow:scroll` - it doesn't scroll `fixed` elements...