# html table with scrollable body: how to make scrolled to the end by default?

Tags: html, css, html-table

My table is similar to [the one suggested by Eamon Nerbonne](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1312678/5433628) in [how do I create an HTML table with fixed/frozen left column and scrollable body?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1312236/5433628). Its code can be found below.

By default, the table appear as `'scrolled: 0% 0%'`, i.e. scrolled to the top left (one can see the cell "AAAA" of row 1).

**Question:** How to make this table `'scrolled: 0% 100%'` by default, i.e. that one can see the top *right* cell when the page is loaded (here cell "ZZZZ" of row 1) as shown in the picture below?

[image: expected output]

---

```css
    body {
  font:16px Calibri;
}
div { 
  width: 600px; 
  overflow-x:scroll;  
  margin-left:5em; 
  overflow-y:visible;
  padding-bottom:1px;
}

table { 
  border-collapse:separate; 
  border-top: 
  3px solid grey;
}

td, th {
  margin:0;
  border:3px solid grey; 
  border-top-width:0px; 
  white-space:nowrap;
}



.headcol {
  position:absolute; 
  width:5em; 
  left:0;
  top:auto;
  border-right: 0px none black; 
  border-top-width:3px; /*only relevant for first row*/
  margin-top:-3px; /*compensate for top border*/
}

.headcol:before {content: 'Row ';}
.long { background:yellow; letter-spacing:1em; }
```

```html
    <div>
  <table>
   <tr>
      <th class="headcol">1</th>
      <td class="long">AAAAA</td>
      <td class="long">BBBBB</td>
      <td class="long">CCCCC</td>
      <td class="long">DDDDD</td>
      <td class="long">EEEEE</td>
      <td class="long">FFFFF</td>
      <td class="long">GGGGG</td>
      <td class="long">HHHHH</td>
      <td class="long">.....</td>
      <td class="long">XXXXX</td>
      <td class="long">YYYYY</td>
      <td class="long">ZZZZZ</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th class="headcol">2</th>
      <td class="long">AAAAA</td>
      <td class="long">BBBBB</td>
      <td class="long">CCCCC</td>
      <td class="long">DDDDD</td>
      <td class="long">EEEEE</td>
      <td class="long">FFFFF</td>
      <td class="long">GGGGG</td>
      <td class="long">HHHHH</td>
      <td class="long">.....</td>
      <td class="long">XXXXX</td>
      <td class="long">YYYYY</td>
      <td class="long">ZZZZZ</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th class="headcol">3</th>
      <td class="long">AAAAA</td>
      <td class="long">BBBBB</td>
      <td class="long">CCCCC</td>
      <td class="long">DDDDD</td>
      <td class="long">EEEEE</td>
      <td class="long">FFFFF</td>
      <td class="long">GGGGG</td>
      <td class="long">HHHHH</td>
      <td class="long">.....</td>
      <td class="long">XXXXX</td>
      <td class="long">YYYYY</td>
      <td class="long">ZZZZZ</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th class="headcol">4</th>
      <td class="long">AAAAA</td>
      <td class="long">BBBBB</td>
      <td class="long">CCCCC</td>
      <td class="long">DDDDD</td>
      <td class="long">EEEEE</td>
      <td class="long">FFFFF</td>
      <td class="long">GGGGG</td>
      <td class="long">HHHHH</td>
      <td class="long">.....</td>
      <td class="long">XXXXX</td>
      <td class="long">YYYYY</td>
      <td class="long">ZZZZZ</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q71adwr0/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve it like this. `direction:rtl` and `direction:ltr` are key here.

JSFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/wpsnkpLk/ (Thanks to ebo)

```
div {
    width: 320px;
    height: 2em;
    overflow: scroll;
    direction:rtl;
}

table{
    direction:ltr;
}
```

**edit:** Based on ebo's comments (thanks!), you need to apply the style to the container containing the table (`div` above) first and then to the table itself for the desired result.

Comment: Very clever. Can't say I've actually had a usage for `rtl` before.

Comment: Caution: the key is actually to use `div{direction:rtl;}` (`div` refering here to the table container) in order to read the table right to left (i.e. initial position of the scroll bar) *and* to use `table{direction:ltr;}` in order to display the columns left to right. Without the latter, columns are printed right to left too, as inherited property: i.e. `[c1 frozen][c4][c3][c2]`. The example was tricky since `c2` and `c3` were the same. Linked JSFiddle is correct, yet here is [another made more explicit](http://jsfiddle.net/wpsnkpLk/)

Comment: @ebo sorry, was a little busy. I have updated the answer based on your comment. Thanks again!