# How can I prevent overlapping of table columns?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I want to make my first column in the table static. Here is my jsfiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/q2ymc76r/12/

css code:

`.table .headcol {
  position:absolute;
}`

Problem is that the first column overlaps with the second column. Any suggestion to prevent the overlapping. Thanks.

Comment: have you tried position: static?

Comment: Static in what way? Is the rest of the table supposed to scroll horizontally? Please edit your question to clarify what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: static did not work.

Comment: Yes the rest of the table should scroll horizontally when we use it in mobile view.

Answer (score 0):

In the following post, as you can read from the title, seems that the user had a similar problem

[how-do-i-create-an-html-table-with-fixed-frozen-left-column-and-scrollable-body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1312236/how-do-i-create-an-html-table-with-fixed-frozen-left-column-and-scrollable-body)

It should cointain something close to the answer your are looking for

Comment: Hi, i've just edited my answer. It's good now, or I have to edit more? Thank you :-)

Answer (score 0):

Just set fixed width to your fisrt column, just like this:

```
<th class="text-center headcol" width="15%">Date</th>
```