# How to lock horizontal scrolling when generating data's dynamically javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm printing data's dynamically in javascript using `document.createElement`. Is there any way to lock the first column when scrolled horizontally?

```
var row = document.createElement("TR");

//Name
var td1 = document.createElement("TD");
var element1 = createSpan(Id, NameName);
td1.appendChild(element1);
row.appendChild(td1);

//Phone
var td2 = document.createElement("TD");
var element2 = createSpan(phoneId, phoneName);
td2.appendChild(element2);
row.appendChild(td2);

//Email
var td2 = document.createElement("TD");
var element2 = createSpan(emailId, emailName);
td2.appendChild(element2);
row.appendChild(td2);
. 
.
.
.
```

I want to lock the **Name** column while scrolling horizontally. So that, the Name stays in the 1st position and the remaining columns moves.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how do I create an HTML table with fixed/frozen left column and scrollable body?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1312236/how-do-i-create-an-html-table-with-fixed-frozen-left-column-and-scrollable-body)

Comment: I tried using `position: absolute` as said in the mentioned thread. It locks the column when moved vertically, but not horizontally.