# Make first column sticky in full calendar io

Tags: php, jquery, fullcalendar

I am using [full calendar io](https://fullcalendar.io/) plugin for my scheduling tool.

I have fixed the header but I can't make the first column as sticky as it has time and I need to make it stay fixed when I scroll towards right end (due to many rooms).

The question is more like making the left most column static in a table since it is full calendar io, it has many classes that are there to generate it. Will need to modify the source code which I am avoiding at the moment.

[image]

When I scroll it right, here is what I see:

[image]

Comment: I'm surprised by your respectable reputation and the fact that your question don't include a single line of code. Where is your [mcve]? Please add it

Comment: @AlonEitan, not sure whether you have used full calendar.io or not, but the API doesn't provide anything to make it static, I am afraid, the code would be irrelevant here since it has nothing to make it look what I need.

Comment: I use it on my projects (Don't know the answer to your question though), I thought you have a code. Thanks for clarifying

Comment: thanks, the question is more like making the left most column static in a table since it is full calendar io it has many classes that are to generate it. Will need to modify the source code which I am avoiding at the moment.

Comment: I suspect that unfortunately you'd have to write a custom view for this, like you say there's nothing built into the calendar, and since it uses a HTML table for the gridview, and then an overlay system for the events, no easy way to make a column stick. This: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1312236/how-do-i-create-an-html-table-with-fixed-frozen-left-column-and-scrollable-body _might_ work, I can't try it now, but it will depend how the overlaid events behave.

Comment: thanks, i was looking at the same question, trying to make it work @ADyson