# How to make <tr>'s height of position:fixed column follow its content's height?

Tags: html, css, html-table

Currently, I have a table in my page and I am trying to make the first column freeze. The freeze column works fine using `position: fixed` for that particular column.

However there is another problem. When the content has more than one row, the `<tr>` doesn't extend its height based on its content. Therefore, is there any solution for this?

Here is my demo:
https://jsfiddle.net/yusrilmaulidanraji/ckfdubsf/121/

```css
#table-wrapper {
  width: 95%;
  float: left;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  background: #ddd;
}

table {
  background: #fff;
  width: 1200px;
  text-align: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

table thead tr th {
  width: 15em;
}

table thead tr th:first-child,
table tbody tr td:first-child {
  top: auto;
  left: 0.5;
  position: fixed;
  width: 6em;
}

table thead tr th:nth-child(2),
table tbody tr td:nth-child(2) {
  padding-left: 7em;
  /*to show second column behind the first*/
}
```

```html
<button id="left">&larr;</button>
<button id="right">&rarr;</button>

<div id="table-wrapper">
  <table border="1">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Heading1</th>
        <th>Heading2</th>
        <th>Heading3</th>
        <th>Heading4</th>
        <th>Heading5</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>1<br/>asdasdada</td>
        <td>12</td>
        <td>13</td>
        <td>14</td>
        <td>15</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>2<br/>asdasdada<br/>asdasdada</td>
        <td>22</td>
        <td>23</td>
        <td>24</td>
        <td>25</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>3<br/>asdasdada</td>
        <td>32</td>
        <td>33</td>
        <td>34</td>
        <td>35</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>4<br/>asdasdada<br/>asdasdada<br/>asdasdada<br/>asdasdada<br/>asdasdada</td>
        <td>42</td>
        <td>43</td>
        <td>44</td>
        <td>45</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>5<br/>asdasdada</td>
        <td>52</td>
        <td>53</td>
        <td>54</td>
        <td>55</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>

</div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how do I create an HTML table with fixed/frozen left column and scrollable body?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1312236/how-do-i-create-an-html-table-with-fixed-frozen-left-column-and-scrollable-body)

Comment: @Terry No I don't think it's a duplicate. My concern in this question is about the `<tr>`'s height, not the freeze column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can go through all td fixed elements and then set those heights to default td elements.

```
  $('table tbody tr td:first-child').each(function(){
      var height = $(this).height();
      $(this).parent().find('td').height(height);
  });
```

Working example https://jsfiddle.net/ckfdubsf/122/

Answer (score 0):

I ended up by using @feesar answer, however I had another issue regarding performance. Therefore, Here is the final result for my case:
https://jsfiddle.net/yusrilmaulidanraji/ckfdubsf/124/

```
  // Adjust the th and td's height.
  // Improve the performance by using native js + for loop.
  var firstHeader = $('#table-wrapper th:first-child');
  firstHeader[0].style.height = firstHeader[0].parentNode.offsetHeight + "px";
  var firstColumn = $('#table-wrapper td:first-child');
  for (var i = 0; i < firstColumn.length; i++) {
    firstColumn[i].parentNode.style.height = firstColumn[i].offsetHeight + "px";
  }
```

The logic and the result are the same, but it has a better performance. Hopefully, it can help.

Answer (score 0):

In terms of performance, I think you will be best off simply cloning the first table column and painting it above the "real" one, like this:

```js
var $overlayTable = $("#table-wrapper table").clone().addClass("overlay");
$overlayTable.find("tr > *:not(:first-child)").remove();
$overlayTable.appendTo("#table-wrapper");

$(window).on("scroll", function () {
    $overlayTable.css("left", $(window).scrollLeft() + "px");
});
```

```css
#table-wrapper {
  position: relative;
}
#table-wrapper table {
  text-align: center;
  table-layout: fixed;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  width: 1200px;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
#table-wrapper table tr > * {
  margin-left: 150px;
  width: auto;
}
#table-wrapper table tr > *:first-child {
  width: 6em;
}
#table-wrapper table.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  color: red;
  background-color: white;
  width: 6em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p>
  <button id="left">&larr;</button>
  <button id="right">&rarr;</button>
</p>

<div id="table-wrapper">
  <table border="1">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Heading1</th>
        <th>Heading2</th>
        <th>Heading3</th>
        <th>Heading4</th>
        <th>Heading5</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>1<br/>asdasdada</td>
        <td>12</td>
        <td>13</td>
        <td>14</td>
        <td>15</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>2<br/>asdasdada<br/>asdasdada</td>
        <td>22</td>
        <td>23</td>
        <td>24</td>
        <td>25</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>3<br/>asdasdada</td>
        <td>32</td>
        <td>33</td>
        <td>34</td>
        <td>35</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>4<br/>asdasdada<br/>asdasdada<br/>asdasdada<br/>asdasdada<br/>asdasdada</td>
        <td>42</td>
        <td>43</td>
        <td>44</td>
        <td>45</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>5<br/>asdasdada</td>
        <td>52</td>
        <td>53</td>
        <td>54</td>
        <td>55</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>

</div>
```

Comment: Nice trick, however there is a glitch in Firefox. When it's scrolled, there is a delay that makes the move of the first column a bit awkward.

Comment: Hm, I'm using Firefox and there's nothing like that here - at least not in the test case above. There might be in your real-world case, I don't know. It's still an option worth exploring. Also, here I've used "absolute" positioning for the clone table, calculating "left" on scroll. You can use "fixed" for the clone table (not the rows/cells!), and calculate "top" and "left" once, if that fits your use case. This should eliminate all flickering.