# Can I create multibody html tables out of restructuredtext tables using sphinx?

Tags: html, python-sphinx, restructuredtext

I want to create a html table with multiple bodies out of a restructuredtext table using sphinx.

I want to use multibody tables to have a different color for different rows in my html table.

```
+----------+----------+
| header_1 | header_2 |
+==========+==========+
|          | cell A1  |
| cell A   +----------+
|          | cell A2  |
+----------+----------+
|          | cell B1  |
| cell B   +----------+
|          | cell B2  |
+----------+----------+
|          | cell C1  |
| cell C   +----------+
|          | cell C2  |
+----------+----------+
|          | cell D1  |
| cell D   +----------+
|          | cell D2  |
+----------+----------+
```

I want row A, C, ... and row B, D, ... to have a different color when compiling to html. The easiest way to do this in my opinion would be to have a different body.

Comment: See my response about [how to use CSS to customize the display of tables in Sphinx](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50687835/2214933).

Comment: Could you explain what you mean with "body" of a table row?