# Can't freeze two first columns with CSS from scrolling

Tags: html, html-table

I make to prevent first two columns from scrolling.
https://jsfiddle.net/kzqbaLu2/1/

I tried to adopt examples from here [how do I create an HTML table with fixed/frozen left column and scrollable body?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1312236/how-do-i-create-an-html-table-with-fixed-frozen-left-column-and-scrollable-body)

But after adding (commented in my example):

```
.headcol {
  position: absolute;
  width: 15em;
  left: 0;
  top: auto;
  border-top-width: 1px;
  margin-top: -1px;
}

.headcol:before {
  content: 'Row ';
}
```

My table begin to look ugly:

[image: https://imgur.com/a/w7TBZ6H]

I need to prevent from scrolling first two column.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/zinoui/BmLpV/ <-- You can refer this jsfiddle to achieve what you want. If you have any questions, you can ask :)

Comment: You have problems with width. Set the widths properly.