# Table first column absolute to parent

Tags: html, css

I am trying to have the first left column of an HTML table always showing even if the user scrolls to the right.

I am trying to adapt the solution that I found on this thread [how do I create an HTML table with fixed/frozen left column and scrollable body?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1312236/how-do-i-create-an-html-table-with-fixed-frozen-left-column-and-scrollable-body) to my needs.

Below you can find a functional example. What I need help with is to be able to position the first column at the same position as the div class "sectionContainer". At this moment it is at the complete left of the whole window (It seems that the absolute positioning  applies to the body tag instead of the parent div).

```css
.sectionContainer {
    margin: 100px;
}
.tableContainer {
  width: 500px;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  margin-left: 110px;
  overflow-y: visible;
  padding: 0;
}
.firstColumn {
    position: absolute;
    width: 90px;
    left: 0;
    border: none !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="sectionContainer">    
<div class="tableContainer">
<table class="table table-bordered" id="gantt">
<thead>
<tr>
    <th class="firstColumn"></th>
    <th colspan="2">12am</th>
    <th colspan="2">1am</th>
    <th colspan="2">2am</th>
    <th colspan="2">3am</th>
    <th colspan="2">4am</th>
    <th colspan="2">5am</th>
    <th colspan="2">6am</th>
    <th colspan="2">7am</th>
    <th colspan="2">8am</th>
    <th colspan="2">9am</th>
    <th colspan="2">10am</th>
    <th colspan="2">11am</th>
    <th colspan="2">12pm</th>
    <th colspan="2">1pm</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<th class="firstColumn"></th>
    <th>00</th>
    <th>30</th>
    <th>00</th>
    <th>30</th>
    <th>00</th>
    <th>30</th>
    <th>00</th>
    <th>30</th>
    <th>00</th>
    <th>30</th>
    <th>00</th>
    <th>30</th>
    <th>00</th>
    <th>30</th>
    <th>00</th>
    <th>00</th>
    <th>30</th>
    <th>00</th>
    <th>30</th>
    <th>00</th>
    <th>30</th>
    <th>00</th>
    <th>30</th>
    <th>00</th>
    <th>30</th>
    <th>00</th>
    <th>30</th>
    <th>00</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr data-crew="1552">
    <th class="firstColumn">Col1</th>
    <td class="empty" data-time="0" data-datetime="2019-01-04 12:00am">&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="empty" data-time="1" data-datetime="2019-01-04 12:30am">&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="empty" data-time="2" data-datetime="2019-01-04 1:00am">&nbsp;</td>

    <td class="empty" data-time="3" data-datetime="2019-01-04 1:30am">&nbsp;</td>

    <td class="empty" data-time="4" data-datetime="2019-01-04 2:00am">&nbsp;</td>

    <td class="empty" data-time="5" data-datetime="2019-01-04 2:30am">&nbsp;</td>

    <td class="empty" data-time="6" data-datetime="2019-01-04 3:00am">&nbsp;</td>

    <td class="empty" data-time="7" data-datetime="2019-01-04 3:30am">&nbsp;</td>

    <td class="empty" data-time="8" data-datetime="2019-01-04 4:00am">&nbsp;</td>

    <td class="empty" data-time="9" data-datetime="2019-01-04 4:30am">&nbsp;</td>

    <td class="empty" data-time="10" data-datetime="2019-01-04 5:00am">&nbsp;</td>

    <td class="empty" data-time="11" data-datetime="2019-01-04 5:30am">&nbsp;</td>

    <td class="empty" data-time="12" data-datetime="2019-01-04 6:00am">&nbsp;</td>

    <td class="empty" data-time="13" data-datetime="2019-01-04 6:30am">&nbsp;</td>

    <td class="empty" data-time="14" data-datetime="2019-01-04 7:00am">&nbsp;</td>

    <td class="empty" data-time="15" data-datetime="2019-01-04 7:30am">&nbsp;</td>

    <td class="empty" data-time="16" data-datetime="2019-01-04 8:00am">&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="empty" data-time="17" data-datetime="2019-01-04 8:30am">&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="empty" data-time="18" data-datetime="2019-01-04 9:00am">&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="empty" data-time="19" data-datetime="2019-01-04 9:30am">&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="empty" data-time="20" data-datetime="2019-01-04 10:00am">&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="empty" data-time="21" data-datetime="2019-01-04 10:30am">&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="empty" data-time="22" data-datetime="2019-01-04 11:00am">&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="empty" data-time="23" data-datetime="2019-01-04 11:30am">&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="empty" data-time="24" data-datetime="2019-01-04 12:00pm">&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="empty" data-time="25" data-datetime="2019-01-04 12:30pm">&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="empty" data-time="26" data-datetime="2019-01-04 1:00pm">&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="empty" data-time="27" data-datetime="2019-01-04 1:30pm">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr data-crew="1551">
<th class="firstColumn">Col2</th>


    <td class="empty" data-time="0" data-datetime="2019-01-04 12:00am">&nbsp;</td>

    <td class="empty" data-time="1" data-datetime="2019-01-04 12:30am">&nbsp;</td>

    <td class="empty" data-time="2" data-datetime="2019-01-04 1:00am">&nbsp;</td>

    <td class="empty" data-time="3" data-datetime="2019-01-04 1:30am">&nbsp;</td>

    <td class="empty" data-time="4" data-datetime="2019-01-04 2:00am">&nbsp;</td>

    <td class="empty" data-time="5" data-datetime="2019-01-04 2:30am">&nbsp;</td>

    <td class="empty" data-time="6" data-datetime="2019-01-04 3:00am">&nbsp;</td>

    <td class="empty" data-time="7" data-datetime="2019-01-04 3:30am">&nbsp;</td>

    <td class="empty" data-time="8" data-datetime="2019-01-04 4:00am">&nbsp;</td>

    <td class="empty" data-time="9" data-datetime="2019-01-04 4:30am">&nbsp;</td>

    <td class="empty" data-time="10" data-datetime="2019-01-04 5:00am">&nbsp;</td>

    <td class="empty" data-time="11" data-datetime="2019-01-04 5:30am">&nbsp;</td>

    <td class="empty" data-time="12" data-datetime="2019-01-04 6:00am">&nbsp;</td>

    <td class="empty" data-time="13" data-datetime="2019-01-04 6:30am">&nbsp;</td>

    <td class="empty" data-time="14" data-datetime="2019-01-04 7:00am">&nbsp;</td>

    <td class="empty" data-time="15" data-datetime="2019-01-04 7:30am">&nbsp;</td>

    <td class="empty" data-time="16" data-datetime="2019-01-04 8:00am">&nbsp;</td>

    <td class="empty" data-time="17" data-datetime="2019-01-04 8:30am">&nbsp;</td>

    <td class="empty" data-time="18" data-datetime="2019-01-04 9:00am">&nbsp;</td>

    <td class="empty" data-time="19" data-datetime="2019-01-04 9:30am">&nbsp;</td>

    <td class="empty" data-time="20" data-datetime="2019-01-04 10:00am">&nbsp;</td>

    <td class="empty" data-time="21" data-datetime="2019-01-04 10:30am">&nbsp;</td>

    <td class="empty" data-time="22" data-datetime="2019-01-04 11:00am">&nbsp;</td>

    <td class="empty" data-time="23" data-datetime="2019-01-04 11:30am">&nbsp;</td>

    <td class="empty" data-time="24" data-datetime="2019-01-04 12:00pm">&nbsp;</td>

    <td class="empty" data-time="25" data-datetime="2019-01-04 12:30pm">&nbsp;</td>

    <td class="empty" data-time="26" data-datetime="2019-01-04 1:00pm">&nbsp;</td>

    <td class="empty" data-time="27" data-datetime="2019-01-04 1:30pm">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you remove some of the `<td>` tags so your code is more of a minimal, complete example? It will make it much easier for others to understand/scroll through.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in the positioning of your elements. Try changing the position set for the `sectionContainer` to `position: absolute;` and it should work as you want.

Added background color so it is easily to see the effect.

```css
.sectionContainer {
    margin: 100px;
    position: absolute;
    background: green;
}
.tableContainer {
  width: 500px;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  margin-left: 110px;
  overflow-y: visible;
  padding: 0;
}
.firstColumn {
    position: absolute;
    width: 90px;
    left: 0;
    border: none !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="sectionContainer">    
<div class="tableContainer">
<table class="table table-bordered" id="gantt">
<thead>
<tr>
    <th class="firstColumn">Text Here</th>
    <th colspan="2">12am</th>
    <th colspan="2">1am</th>
    <th colspan="2">2am</th>
    <th colspan="2">3am</th>
    <th colspan="2">4am</th>
    <th colspan="2">5am</th>
    <th colspan="2">6am</th>
    <th colspan="2">7am</th>
    <th colspan="2">8am</th>
    <th colspan="2">9am</th>
    <th colspan="2">10am</th>
    <th colspan="2">11am</th>
    <th colspan="2">12pm</th>
    <th colspan="2">1pm</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<th class="firstColumn">Text Here</th>
    <th>00</th>
    <th>30</th>
    <th>00</th>
    <th>30</th>
    <th>00</th>
    <th>30</th>
    <th>00</th>
    <th>30</th>
    <th>00</th>
    <th>30</th>
    <th>00</th>
    <th>30</th>
    <th>00</th>
    <th>30</th>
    <th>00</th>
    <th>00</th>
    <th>30</th>
    <th>00</th>
    <th>30</th>
    <th>00</th>
    <th>30</th>
    <th>00</th>
    <th>30</th>
    <th>00</th>
    <th>30</th>
    <th>00</th>
    <th>30</th>
    <th>00</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr data-crew="1552">
    <th class="firstColumn">Col1</th>
    <td class="empty" data-time="0" data-datetime="2019-01-04 12:00am">&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="empty" data-time="1" data-datetime="2019-01-04 12:30am">&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="empty" data-time="2" data-datetime="2019-01-04 1:00am">&nbsp;</td>

    <td class="empty" data-time="3" data-datetime="2019-01-04 1:30am">&nbsp;</td>

    <td class="empty" data-time="4" data-datetime="2019-01-04 2:00am">&nbsp;</td>

    <td class="empty" data-time="5" data-datetime="2019-01-04 2:30am">&nbsp;</td>

    <td class="empty" data-time="6" data-datetime="2019-01-04 3:00am">&nbsp;</td>

    <td class="empty" data-time="7" data-datetime="2019-01-04 3:30am">&nbsp;</td>

    <td class="empty" data-time="8" data-datetime="2019-01-04 4:00am">&nbsp;</td>

    <td class="empty" data-time="9" data-datetime="2019-01-04 4:30am">&nbsp;</td>

    <td class="empty" data-time="10" data-datetime="2019-01-04 5:00am">&nbsp;</td>

    <td class="empty" data-time="11" data-datetime="2019-01-04 5:30am">&nbsp;</td>

    <td class="empty" data-time="12" data-datetime="2019-01-04 6:00am">&nbsp;</td>

    <td class="empty" data-time="13" data-datetime="2019-01-04 6:30am">&nbsp;</td>

    <td class="empty" data-time="14" data-datetime="2019-01-04 7:00am">&nbsp;</td>

    <td class="empty" data-time="15" data-datetime="2019-01-04 7:30am">&nbsp;</td>

    <td class="empty" data-time="16" data-datetime="2019-01-04 8:00am">&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="empty" data-time="17" data-datetime="2019-01-04 8:30am">&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="empty" data-time="18" data-datetime="2019-01-04 9:00am">&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="empty" data-time="19" data-datetime="2019-01-04 9:30am">&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="empty" data-time="20" data-datetime="2019-01-04 10:00am">&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="empty" data-time="21" data-datetime="2019-01-04 10:30am">&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="empty" data-time="22" data-datetime="2019-01-04 11:00am">&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="empty" data-time="23" data-datetime="2019-01-04 11:30am">&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="empty" data-time="24" data-datetime="2019-01-04 12:00pm">&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="empty" data-time="25" data-datetime="2019-01-04 12:30pm">&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="empty" data-time="26" data-datetime="2019-01-04 1:00pm">&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="empty" data-time="27" data-datetime="2019-01-04 1:30pm">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr data-crew="1551">
<th class="firstColumn">Col2</th>


    <td class="empty" data-time="0" data-datetime="2019-01-04 12:00am">&nbsp;</td>

    <td class="empty" data-time="1" data-datetime="2019-01-04 12:30am">&nbsp;</td>

    <td class="empty" data-time="2" data-datetime="2019-01-04 1:00am">&nbsp;</td>

    <td class="empty" data-time="3" data-datetime="2019-01-04 1:30am">&nbsp;</td>

    <td class="empty" data-time="4" data-datetime="2019-01-04 2:00am">&nbsp;</td>

    <td class="empty" data-time="5" data-datetime="2019-01-04 2:30am">&nbsp;</td>

    <td class="empty" data-time="6" data-datetime="2019-01-04 3:00am">&nbsp;</td>

    <td class="empty" data-time="7" data-datetime="2019-01-04 3:30am">&nbsp;</td>

    <td class="empty" data-time="8" data-datetime="2019-01-04 4:00am">&nbsp;</td>

    <td class="empty" data-time="9" data-datetime="2019-01-04 4:30am">&nbsp;</td>

    <td class="empty" data-time="10" data-datetime="2019-01-04 5:00am">&nbsp;</td>

    <td class="empty" data-time="11" data-datetime="2019-01-04 5:30am">&nbsp;</td>

    <td class="empty" data-time="12" data-datetime="2019-01-04 6:00am">&nbsp;</td>

    <td class="empty" data-time="13" data-datetime="2019-01-04 6:30am">&nbsp;</td>

    <td class="empty" data-time="14" data-datetime="2019-01-04 7:00am">&nbsp;</td>

    <td class="empty" data-time="15" data-datetime="2019-01-04 7:30am">&nbsp;</td>

    <td class="empty" data-time="16" data-datetime="2019-01-04 8:00am">&nbsp;</td>

    <td class="empty" data-time="17" data-datetime="2019-01-04 8:30am">&nbsp;</td>

    <td class="empty" data-time="18" data-datetime="2019-01-04 9:00am">&nbsp;</td>

    <td class="empty" data-time="19" data-datetime="2019-01-04 9:30am">&nbsp;</td>

    <td class="empty" data-time="20" data-datetime="2019-01-04 10:00am">&nbsp;</td>

    <td class="empty" data-time="21" data-datetime="2019-01-04 10:30am">&nbsp;</td>

    <td class="empty" data-time="22" data-datetime="2019-01-04 11:00am">&nbsp;</td>

    <td class="empty" data-time="23" data-datetime="2019-01-04 11:30am">&nbsp;</td>

    <td class="empty" data-time="24" data-datetime="2019-01-04 12:00pm">&nbsp;</td>

    <td class="empty" data-time="25" data-datetime="2019-01-04 12:30pm">&nbsp;</td>

    <td class="empty" data-time="26" data-datetime="2019-01-04 1:00pm">&nbsp;</td>

    <td class="empty" data-time="27" data-datetime="2019-01-04 1:30pm">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Setting position to relative works too. absolute did not work for me when I integrated in the original page in the app.