# Angular table with last columns fixed

Tags: angular, responsive

I need to have a table with last columns fixed, i have already try somes solution but nothing works great.

I'm need to have this render but without width.
https://web.archive.org/web/20130909085817/http://datatables.net/release-datatables/extras/FixedColumns/right_column.html

Anyone of you have a directive ore something with angular for help me?

Thanks you.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1312236/how-do-i-create-an-html-table-with-fixed-frozen-left-column-and-scrollable-body ??

Comment: you can use Angular Material Table. Example: https://stackblitz.com/angular/pxgenqnknmlx?file=app%2Ftable-sticky-columns-example.ts.

Comment: if you are trying to build the table on your own take a look at this approach https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1312236/how-do-i-create-an-html-table-with-fixed-frozen-left-column-and-scrollable-body

Answer (score 0):

Try this, a rich library that acts as an Angular component and allows you to easily and efficiently match both functionality and design

[ag-grid](https://www.ag-grid.com/)