# how to set scrollbars on multiple divs, but not all divs

Tags: html, css, css-grid

where is snipet?

i want to set scrollbar on only body part.  not rheader and cheader.

if i set
`overflow: scroll;`
to body div, separate scrollbars on each body div.
this is not i want.
one scrollbar whole over body divs.

---

rheader and cheader always on same position.

If i set
`position: sticky;`
to cheader and rheader div,
this is almost i want,
but scrollbar must on only body div.
not on rheader and cheader

see snipet.

```
<div>
  <div>
    .
  </div>
  <div class="cheader">
    cheader
  </div>
  <div class="cheader">
    cheader
  </div>
  <div class="rheader">
    rheader
  </div>
  <div class="body">
    body
  </div>
  <div class="body">
    body
  </div>
  <div class="rheader">
    rheader
  </div>
  <div class="body">
    body
  </div>
  <div class="body">
    body
  </div>
</div>
```

```
body > div {
  display: grid;
  grid-template:
    ". cheader cheader " 3rem
    "rheader body body " 3rem
    "rheader body body " 3rem
    / 10rem 1fr 1fr;
  width: 500px;
  height: 30px;
}

body > div div {
  border: 1px solid;
}

.body {
  overflow: scroll;
}
```

[this is wrong scrollbar image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XlMud.png)

[scrollbars on whole div with position sticky.  this works, but i do not want scrollbars on cheader and rheader](https://i.stack.imgur.com/byNoU.png)

[this is right image of body scrollbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QnhcY.png)

please mention that scroll bar not on rheader and cheader.

Comment: if you don't want scrollbars then don't use `overflow: scroll`

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76572755/6676790), by freeze the first row and first column.
The solution provided by dilip_kumar is in line with your needs.