# how to break long content without overlap in a sticky table header

Tags: html, css, html-table

I'm trying to make table header (left column) frozen while scrolling.

I followed this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1312678), however I find that when table header content is larger than cell, the content breaks but it overlaps on the next row. or the rows don't show aligned.

```css
body {
  font: 16px Calibri;
}

table {
  border-collapse: separate;
  border-spacing: 0;
}

td,
th {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 8px;
}

div {
  overflow-x: scroll;
  margin-left: 5em;
  overflow-y: visible;
  padding-bottom: 1px;
}

.headcol {
  position: absolute;
  width: 5rem;
  left: 0;
  top: auto;
  display: block;
  word-break: break-all;
  border: 1px solid grey;
}

 td {
      border: 1px solid grey;
    }

.long {
  letter-spacing: 1em;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th class="headcol">row row row 1</th>
      <td class="long">QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM</td>
      <td class="long">QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th class="headcol">row row 2</th>
      <td class="long">QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM</td>
      <td class="long">QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th class="headcol">row row row row 3</th>
      <td class="long">QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM</td>
      <td class="long">QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th class="headcol">4</th>
      <td class="long">QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM</td>
      <td class="long">QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th class="headcol">5</th>
      <td class="long">QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM</td>
      <td class="long">QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th class="headcol">row row row6</th>
      <td class="long">QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM</td>
      <td class="long">QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th class="headcol">7</th>
      <td class="long">QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM</td>
      <td class="long">QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th class="headcol">8</th>
      <td class="long">QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM</td>
      <td class="long">QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th class="headcol">9</th>
      <td class="long">QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM</td>
      <td class="long">QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

I made a working fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/epkoayzx

it seems that table cells td/th don't expand accordingly to content. how to fix this?

Comment: What do you want to happen? The data rows are still lined up with the headers. Its just the headers introduce gaps in that they push down the next row.

Comment: I want table head and table cell td to have same height when table head content is long. I added border to show that it doesnt look aligned