# How to make a normal Html table to be looks like flexigrid?

Tags: html, html-table, flexigrid

I want to know how to convert a normal html table to be looked like flexigrid. Is it possible to avoid scrolling of headers in the table like flexigrid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible to fix the head with CSS. It will always stay visible on top.

```
<table>
 <thead style="position:fixed; top:0px; z-index:42; background:#fff;">
  <tr>
   <th>head cell a</th>
   <th>head cell b</th>
  </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
  <tr>
   <td>1a</td>
   <td>1b</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>2a</td>
   <td>2b</td>
  </tr>
  <!-- ... -->
 </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: okay. I found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/684211/html-table-with-fixed-headers-and-a-fixed-column and this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/673153/html-table-with-fixed-headers

Comment: This solution is works only in firefox. Not in IE.