# How can I make the first and second column of a table sticky

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css-tables, sticky

i have a `div` with with property

```
<div id="_body_container" style="height: 500px; overflow-x: auto; overflow-y: auto; ">
</div>`
```

inside this div i have the `table` which has class `views-table`, this table has 100% width which makes it's parent div:`_body_container` scrollable.I want to fix the first and the second column of this table sticky at their positions while the left and right scroll event happen for `_body_container`

structure is like:[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [HTML table with fixed headers and a fixed column?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/684211/html-table-with-fixed-headers-and-a-fixed-column)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Assuming each section is a `<td>` element...

**CSS**

```
table {
    position: relative;
    padding-left: (width-of-your-td-elements);
}
table td:first-of-type {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
}
```

Try that out. It's late and I'm drunk, so I'm not entirely sure on this. Oh, and keep in mind this is using CSS3, which isn't supported in <= IE8.

If this works, you could just add `position:absolute; left:0;` to a `class` and target the first element that way.

Comment: i already tried this one. if the position absolute to the first column it's not any more inside the scrollable window it become visible to the entire page up to it's height.

Comment: That's why you set `position: relative;` on the parent element.

Comment: i think it's work, need some modification. Thanks for your attention

Comment: yeah, it does. i'll tackle it tomorrow if it still hasn't been solved. and no problem!

Comment: Actually laughed out loud at "It's late and I'm drunk, so I'm not entirely sure on this".

Answer (score 4):

@vonkly is almost right about `position:absolute`. But you don't have to set `left:0`. With `left:auto`, you can spare `position:relative` too.

```
table {
    padding-left: (width-of-your-td-elements);
}

table td:first-of-type {
    position: absolute;
}
```