# Making first column of Bootstrap responsive table fixed, even on iPhone

Tags: jquery, css, iphone, twitter-bootstrap

In testing out the solution from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19737306/bootstrap-3-responsive-table-with-fixed-first-column/19739775#19739775), I found that the fixed column does not work in certain mobile situations (iPhone). I was wondering how that solution could be tweaked in order to make it work for iPhone users as well.

Also, apologies for posting this as a separate question - would have loved to have made this just a comment on that old question, but that requires 50 rep. points...which someone new to posting on SO like me just doesn't have!

Comment: In that question the first column is positioned absolute, are you sure it doesn't work in IOS? Have you tested it? Here's more stuff to look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7684111/how-can-i-make-the-first-and-second-column-of-a-table-sticky https://github.com/markmalek/Fixed-Header-Table