# jQuery plugin to float BOTH column AND row headers

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, html-table, css-float

I have an HTML `<table>` that is both wide and tall.  Because it requires both horizontal vertical scrolling, I would like to use jQuery to float the column headers (`<thead>`) **AND** the row headers (`<th>` tags in the `<tbody>`).

There seem to be plenty of plugins that do the `<thead>` (such as [this](http://rommelsantor.com/jquery/thfloat/demo.php)), but are there any that do both column and row headers?

Note that I am **not** looking for a plugin that adds scrollbars to the sides of my table.  I want the headers to float if they scroll off the browser window.

Comment: possible duplicate of [HTML table with fixed headers and a fixed column?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/684211/html-table-with-fixed-headers-and-a-fixed-column)

Comment: @mblase75 - I'm not looking for a solution that adds scrollbars to the table.  I have edited my question to clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://meetselva.github.io/fixed-table-rows-cols/

Is a jQuery plugin that fits the bill perfectly!