# Table with fixed header and fixed column on pure css

Tags: html, css, html-table, markup, fixed-header-tables

I need to create a html table (or something similar looking) with a fixed header and a fixed first column.

Every solution I've seen so far uses Javascript or `jQuery` to set scrollTop/scrollLeft, but it doesn't work smoothly on mobile browsers, so I'm looking for a pure CSS solution.

I found a solution for a fixed column here: [jsfiddle.net/C8Dtf/20/](http://jsfiddle.net/C8Dtf/20/) but I don't know how I can enhance it to make the header fixed too.

I want it to work on webkit browsers or use some `css3` features, but I repeat, I don't want to use `Javascript` for scrolling.

**EDIT:** This is example of the behaviour I want to achieve: https://web.archive.org/web/20130829032141/http://datatables.net/release-datatables/extras/FixedColumns/css_size.html

Comment: I dont see where <html> <table> with fixed header <thead> has to do with css-level-3 for the moment. What else do you have ? What have you tried so far ?

Comment: I've tried to apply complex `position` behavior to rows and cells, but I don't quite understand where it is apllicable or not.

Comment: This answer may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14834198/table-scroll-with-html-and-css/22801367#22801367

Answer (score 210):

The `position: sticky` property supports both sticking to the top and to the side in modern versions of Chrome, Firefox, and Edge. This can be combined with a `div` that has the `overflow: scroll` property to give you a table with fixed headers that can be placed anywhere on your page.

Place your table in a container:

```
<div class="container">
  <table></table>
</div>
```

Use `overflow: scroll` on your container to enable scrolling:

```
div.container {
  overflow: scroll;
}
```

As [Dagmar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1912127/dagmar) pointed out in the comments, the container also requires a `max-width` and a `max-height`.

Use `position: sticky` to have table cells stick to the edge and `top`, `right`, or `left` to choose which edge to stick to:

```
thead th {
  position: -webkit-sticky; /* for Safari */
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}

tbody th {
  position: -webkit-sticky; /* for Safari */
  position: sticky;
  left: 0;
}
```

As [MarredCheese](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5405967/marredcheese) mentioned in the comments, if your first column contains `<td>` elements instead of `<th>` elements, you can use `tbody td:first-child` in your CSS instead of `tbody th`

To have the header in the first column stick to the left, use:

```
thead th:first-child {
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```css
/* Use overflow:scroll on your container to enable scrolling: */

div {
  max-width: 400px;
  max-height: 150px;
  overflow: scroll;
}


/* Use position: sticky to have it stick to the edge
 * and top, right, or left to choose which edge to stick to: */

thead th {
  position: -webkit-sticky; /* for Safari */
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}

tbody th {
  position: -webkit-sticky; /* for Safari */
  position: sticky;
  left: 0;
}


/* To have the header in the first column stick to the left: */

thead th:first-child {
  left: 0;
  z-index: 2;
}


/* Just to display it nicely: */

thead th {
  background: #000;
  color: #FFF;
  /* Ensure this stays above the emulated border right in tbody th {}: */
  z-index: 1;
}

tbody th {
  background: #FFF;
  border-right: 1px solid #CCC;
  /* Browsers tend to drop borders on sticky elements, so we emulate the border-right using a box-shadow to ensure it stays: */
  box-shadow: 1px 0 0 0 #ccc;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td,
th {
  padding: 0.5em;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th>headheadhead</th>
        <th>headheadhead</th>
        <th>headheadhead</th>
        <th>headheadhead</th>
        <th>headheadhead</th>
        <th>headheadhead</th>
        <th>headheadhead</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th>head</th>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>head</th>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>head</th>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>head</th>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>head</th>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>head</th>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/qwubvg9m/1/

Comment: upvoted! how would you do 2 columns sticky instead of one with this

Comment: @PirateApp If you know the `width` of your first column, you can use `position: sticky` on the cells in your second column with a `left` value equal to your first column's `width`: https://jsfiddle.net/wvypo83c/794/

Comment: @PussInBoots It depends on the browser, but according to [caniuse](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sticky) it should work on mobile Chrome, Firefox, and Safari (with the `-webkit-` prefix)

Comment: This doesn't work without a max-width and max-height set on the container.

Comment: This answer is a lighthouse guiding us home through the endless sea of malfunctioning, overcomplicated, time-wasting answers from surprisingly-confident, bafflingly-upvoted posters here on SO and across the web.  Note that if your first column contains `<td>` elements instead of `<th>` elements, you can use `tbody td:first-child` in your CSS instead of `tbody th`.

Comment: This is so cool! Also if you want 1st column header you can add some `z-index` to make it not overlapped by other sticky's

Comment: how to get a `border-right: 1px solid` to stay visible on the first column?

Comment: @user1063287 Most browsers drop the border for sticky elements on scroll, but you can emulate the same effect of a border more reliably on sticky elements by using a box-shadow like `box-shadow: 1px 0 0 0 #ccc;`

Comment: Instead of overflow: scroll you can use overflow: auto; this way the scrollbar only shows up when the content is too large.

Comment: @user1063287 When using border-collapse: separate; instead of border-collapse: collapse; the border on the first column stays visible.

Answer (score 46):

Nowadays, this **is possible** to achieve using **CSS only** with `position: sticky` property.

Here goes a snippet:

(jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/hbqzdzdt/5/)

```css
.grid-container {
  display: grid; /* This is a (hacky) way to make the .grid element size to fit its content */
  overflow: auto;
  height: 300px;
  width: 600px;
}
.grid {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
}
.grid-col {
  width: 150px;
  min-width: 150px;
}

.grid-item--header {
  height: 100px;
  min-height: 100px;
  position: sticky;
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  background: white;
  top: 0;
}

.grid-col--fixed-left {
  position: sticky;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 9998;
  background: white;
}
.grid-col--fixed-right {
  position: sticky;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 9998;
  background: white;
}

.grid-item {
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="grid">
    <div class="grid-col grid-col--fixed-left">
      <div class="grid-item grid-item--header">
        <p>HEAD</p>
      </div>
      <div class="grid-item">
        <p>Hello</p>
      </div>
      <div class="grid-item">
        <p>Hello</p>
      </div>
      <div class="grid-item">
        <p>Hello</p>
      </div>
      <div class="grid-item">
        <p>Hello</p>
      </div>
      <div class="grid-item">
        <p>Hello</p>
      </div>
      <div class="grid-item">
        <p>Hello</p>
      </div>
      <div class="grid-item">
        <p>Hello</p>
      </div>
      <div class="grid-item">
        <p>Hello</p>
      </div>
      <div class="grid-item">
        <p>Hello</p>
      </div>
      <div class="grid-item">
        <p>Hello</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="grid-col">
      <div class="grid-item grid-item--header">
        <p>HEAD</p>
      </div>
      <div class="grid-item">
        <p>P</p>
      </div>
      <div class="grid-item">
        <p>P</p>
      </div>
      <div class="grid-item">
        <p>P</p>
      </div>
      <div class="grid-item">
        <p>P</p>
      </div>
      <div class="grid-item">
        <p>P</p>
      </div>
      <div class="grid-item">
        <p>P</p>
      </div>
      <div class="grid-item">
        <p>P</p>
      </div>
      <div class="grid-item">
        <p>P</p>
      </div>
      <div class="grid-item">
        <p>P</p>
      </div>
      <div class="grid-item">
        <p>P</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="grid-col">
      <div class="grid-item grid-item--header">
        <p>HEAD</p>
      </div>
      <div class="grid-item">
        <p>P</p>
      </div>
      <div class="grid-item">
        <p>P</p>
      </div>
      <div class="grid-item">
        <p>P</p>
      </div>
      <div class="grid-item">
        <p>P</p>
      </div>
      <div class="grid-item">
        <p>P</p>
      </div>
      <div class="grid-item">
        <p>P</p>
      </div>
      <div class="grid-item">
        <p>P</p>
      </div>
      <div class="grid-item">
        <p>P</p>
      </div>
      <div class="grid-item">
        <p>P</p>
      </div>
      <div class="grid-item">
        <p>P</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="grid-col">
      <div class="grid-item grid-item--header">
        <p>HEAD</p>
      </div>
      <div class="grid-item">
        <p>P</p>
      </div>
      <div class="grid-item">
        <p>P</p>
      </div>
      <div class="grid-item">
        <p>P</p>
      </div>
      <div class="grid-item">
        <p>P</p>
      </div>
      <div class="grid-item">
        <p>P</p>
      </div>
      <div class="grid-item">
        <p>P</p>
      </div>
      <div class="grid-item">
        <p>P</p>
      </div>
      <div class="grid-item">
        <p>P</p>
      </div>
      <div class="grid-item">
        <p>P</p>
      </div>
      <div class="grid-item">
        <p>P</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="grid-col">
      <div class="grid-item grid-item--header">
        <p>HEAD</p>
      </div>
      <div class="grid-item">
        <p>P</p>
      </div>
      <div class="grid-item">
        <p>P</p>
      </div>
      <div class="grid-item">
        <p>P</p>
      </div>
      <div class="grid-item">
        <p>P</p>
      </div>
      <div class="grid-item">
        <p>P</p>
      </div>
      <div class="grid-item">
        <p>P</p>
      </div>
      <div class="grid-item">
        <p>P</p>
      </div>
      <div class="grid-item">
        <p>P</p>
      </div>
      <div class="grid-item">
        <p>P</p>
      </div>
      <div class="grid-item">
        <p>P</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="grid-col">
      <div class="grid-item grid-item--header">
        <p>HEAD</p>
      </div>
      <div class="grid-item">
        <p>P</p>
      </div>
      <div class="grid-item">
        <p>P</p>
      </div>
      <div class="grid-item">
        <p>P</p>
      </div>
      <div class="grid-item">
        <p>P</p>
      </div>
      <div class="grid-item">
        <p>P</p>
      </div>
      <div class="grid-item">
        <p>P</p>
      </div>
      <div class="grid-item">
        <p>P</p>
      </div>
      <div class="grid-item">
        <p>P</p>
      </div>
      <div class="grid-item">
        <p>P</p>
      </div>
      <div class="grid-item">
        <p>P</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="grid-col">
      <div class="grid-item grid-item--header">
        <p>HEAD</p>
      </div>
      <div class="grid-item">
        <p>P</p>
      </div>
      <div class="grid-item">
        <p>P</p>
      </div>
      <div class="grid-item">
        <p>P</p>
      </div>
      <div class="grid-item">
        <p>P</p>
      </div>
      <div class="grid-item">
        <p>P</p>
      </div>
      <div class="grid-item">
        <p>P</p>
      </div>
      <div class="grid-item">
        <p>P</p>
      </div>
      <div class="grid-item">
        <p>P</p>
      </div>
      <div class="grid-item">
        <p>P</p>
      </div>
      <div class="grid-item">
        <p>P</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="grid-col">
      <div class="grid-item grid-item--header">
        <p>HEAD</p>
      </div>
      <div class="grid-item">
        <p>P</p>
      </div>
      <div class="grid-item">
        <p>P</p>
      </div>
      <div class="grid-item">
        <p>P</p>
      </div>
      <div class="grid-item">
        <p>P</p>
      </div>
      <div class="grid-item">
        <p>P</p>
      </div>
      <div class="grid-item">
        <p>P</p>
      </div>
      <div class="grid-item">
        <p>P</p>
      </div>
      <div class="grid-item">
        <p>P</p>
      </div>
      <div class="grid-item">
        <p>P</p>
      </div>
      <div class="grid-item">
        <p>P</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="grid-col">
      <div class="grid-item grid-item--header">
        <p>HEAD</p>
      </div>
      <div class="grid-item">
        <p>P</p>
      </div>
      <div class="grid-item">
        <p>P</p>
      </div>
      <div class="grid-item">
        <p>P</p>
      </div>
      <div class="grid-item">
        <p>P</p>
      </div>
      <div class="grid-item">
        <p>P</p>
      </div>
      <div class="grid-item">
        <p>P</p>
      </div>
      <div class="grid-item">
        <p>P</p>
      </div>
      <div class="grid-item">
        <p>P</p>
      </div>
      <div class="grid-item">
        <p>P</p>
      </div>
      <div class="grid-item">
        <p>P</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="grid-col">
      <div class="grid-item grid-item--header">
        <p>HEAD</p>
      </div>
      <div class="grid-item">
        <p>P</p>
      </div>
      <div class="grid-item">
        <p>P</p>
      </div>
      <div class="grid-item">
        <p>P</p>
      </div>
      <div class="grid-item">
        <p>P</p>
      </div>
      <div class="grid-item">
        <p>P</p>
      </div>
      <div class="grid-item">
        <p>P</p>
      </div>
      <div class="grid-item">
        <p>P</p>
      </div>
      <div class="grid-item">
        <p>P</p>
      </div>
      <div class="grid-item">
        <p>P</p>
      </div>
      <div class="grid-item">
        <p>P</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="grid-col">
      <div class="grid-item grid-item--header">
        <p>HEAD</p>
      </div>
      <div class="grid-item">
        <p>P</p>
      </div>
      <div class="grid-item">
        <p>P</p>
      </div>
      <div class="grid-item">
        <p>P</p>
      </div>
      <div class="grid-item">
        <p>P</p>
      </div>
      <div class="grid-item">
        <p>P</p>
      </div>
      <div class="grid-item">
        <p>P</p>
      </div>
      <div class="grid-item">
        <p>P</p>
      </div>
      <div class="grid-item">
        <p>P</p>
      </div>
      <div class="grid-item">
        <p>P</p>
      </div>
      <div class="grid-item">
        <p>P</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="grid-col grid-col--fixed-right">
      <div class="grid-item grid-item--header">
        <p>HEAD</p>
      </div>
      <div class="grid-item">
        <p>9</p>
      </div>
      <div class="grid-item">
        <p>9</p>
      </div>
      <div class="grid-item">
        <p>9</p>
      </div>
      <div class="grid-item">
        <p>9</p>
      </div>
      <div class="grid-item">
        <p>9</p>
      </div>
      <div class="grid-item">
        <p>9</p>
      </div>
      <div class="grid-item">
        <p>9</p>
      </div>
      <div class="grid-item">
        <p>9</p>
      </div>
      <div class="grid-item">
        <p>9</p>
      </div>
      <div class="grid-item">
        <p>9</p>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Regarding compatibility. It works in all major browsers, but not in IE. There is a polyfill for `position: sticky` but I never tried it.

Comment: any way to achieve this with <table>-tags and not <div>

Comment: I think this is not going to have good performance if you are developing an application and need to loop through records to print this table because for every column in the table, you have to loop through the entire record's array. This HTML works column by column.

Comment: @igasparetto You can actually arrange the rows/columns the other way around and the solution would still work. If I have some time later I can create a snippet with the grid ordered row -> column.

Comment: I would advise against displaying tabular data without using <table> and associated tags. There are several issues with breaking the intended use of HTML in this way, including accessibility. See also: https://www.w3.org/WAI/tutorials/tables/

Answer (score 15):

**This is no easy feat.**

The following link is to a working demo:

**Link Updated according to lanoxx's comment**

http://jsfiddle.net/C8Dtf/366/

Just remember to add these:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="http://datatables.net/release-datatables/media/js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="http://datatables.net/release-datatables/media/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="http://datatables.net/release-datatables/extras/FixedColumns/media/js/FixedColumns.js"></script>
```

i don't see any other way of achieving this. **Especially not by using css only.**

This is a lot to go through. *Hope this helps :)*

Comment: To switch of the filter use:    
`"bFilter": false`

Comment: It *is* possible to achieve this with css only. Not easy but possible.

Comment: from about 10 solutions this was the only one that worked. Btw, to remove the "Showing 1 to 57 of 57 entries" add `"bInfo" : false` into the `.dataTable()` call

Comment: datatables == "awesome"

Comment: downvoting this solution because it is bad. the `thead` is in its own table which isn't bound to changes of `td` elements, so if a cell text is long, the `th` width will not adjust accordingly.

Comment: This answer is outdated. Nowadays It is possible to do using CSS only.
See https://stackoverflow.com/a/46919521/4436816.

Answer (score 15):

All of these suggestions are great and all, but they're either only fixing either the header or a column, not both, or they're using javascript. The reason - it don't believe it can be done in pure CSS. The reason:

If it were possible to do it, you would need to nest several scrollable divs one inside the other, each with a scroll in a different direction. Then you would need to split your table into three parts - the fixed header, the fixed column and the rest of the data.

Fine. But now the problem - you can make one of them stay put when you scroll, but the other one is nested inside the scrolling area of first and is therefore subject to being scrolled out of sight itself, so can't be fixed in place on the screen. 'Ah-ha' you say 'but I can somehow use absolute or fixed position to do that' - no you can't. As soon as you do that you lose the ability to scroll that container. It's a chicken and egg situation - you can't have both, they cancel each other out.

I believe the only solution is through javascript. You need to completely seperate out the three elements and keep their positions in sync through javascript. There are good examples in other posts on this page. This one is also worth a look:

http://tympanus.net/codrops/2014/01/09/sticky-table-headers-columns/

Answer (score 9):

I've made some changes in in jsfiddle. This might be what you're trying to do.

> http://jsfiddle.net/C8Dtf/81/

I have hardcoded the titles like so:

```
<table id="left_table" class="freeze_table">
    <tr class='tblTitle'>
         <th>Title 1</th>
         <th>Title 2</th>
    </tr>
</table>
```

And I added some styles as well.

```
.tblTitle{
   position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    margin-bottom:30px;
    background:lightblue;
}
td, th{
    padding:5px;
    height:40px;
    width:40px;
    font-size:14px;
}
```

*Hope this is what you want :)*

Comment: I need a header of the right table to scroll together with its content.

Comment: Here is the URL: http://jsfiddle.net/C8Dtf/84/ . You just need to play around with the styling for the right-hand table to align the two tables.

Comment: No. You don't quite understand. I need the header of the right table to be fixed to the top so it would be still visible when the table scrolls up and down, but when the table scrolls right or left header must scroll right or left but still be fixed at the top. Sorry me for my bad English skills.

Comment: So want the right-hand table's header to be fixed when scrolling vertically, and to scroll when scrolling horizontally?

Comment: This is example of the behaviour I want to achieve: http://datatables.net/release-datatables/extras/FixedColumns/css_size.html

Comment: Though the header of the right-handle table doesn't scroll, this is still a very cool solution. Particularly how it is the only solution which allows `table-layout: auto`. For smaller tables the header issue can be resolved with a scroll listener, here's an [example using React](https://jsfiddle.net/calebthebrewer/jsc6z1u8/)(not fully styled so a bit ugly...)

Answer (score 9):

An example using only CSS:

```css
.table {
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 500px;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

.header th {
  font-family: Calibri;
  font-size: small;
  font-weight: lighter;
  border-left: 1px solid #000;
  background: #d0d0d0;
}

.body_panel {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 520px;
  height: 300px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.body tr {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #d0d0d0;
}

.body td {
  border-left: 1px solid #d0d0d0;
  padding-left: 3px;
  font-family: Calibri;
  font-size: small;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<body>

  <table class="table">

    <thead class="header">

      <tr>
        <th style="width:20%;">teste</th>
        <th style="width:30%;">teste 2</th>
        <th style="width:50%;">teste 3</th>
      </tr>

    </thead>
  </table>

  <div class="body_panel">

    <table class="table">
      <tbody class="body">

        <tr>
          <td style="width:20%;">asbkj k kajsb ksb kabkb</td>
          <td style="width:30%;">2</td>
          <td style="width:50%;">3</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td style="width:20%;">2</td>
          <td style="width:30%;">2</td>
          <td style="width:50%;">3</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td style="width:20%;">2</td>
          <td style="width:30%;">2</td>
          <td style="width:50%;">3</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td style="width:20%;">2</td>
          <td style="width:30%;">2</td>
          <td style="width:50%;">3</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td style="width:20%;">2</td>
          <td style="width:30%;">2</td>
          <td style="width:50%;">3</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td style="width:20%;">2</td>
          <td style="width:30%;">2</td>
          <td style="width:50%;">3</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td style="width:20%;">2</td>
          <td style="width:30%;">2</td>
          <td style="width:50%;">3</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td style="width:20%;">2</td>
          <td style="width:30%;">2</td>
          <td style="width:50%;">3</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td style="width:20%;">2</td>
          <td style="width:30%;">2</td>
          <td style="width:50%;">3</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td style="width:20%;">2</td>
          <td style="width:30%;">2</td>
          <td style="width:50%;">3</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td style="width:20%;">2</td>
          <td style="width:30%;">2</td>
          <td style="width:50%;">3</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td style="width:20%;">2</td>
          <td style="width:30%;">2</td>
          <td style="width:50%;">3</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td style="width:20%;">2</td>
          <td style="width:30%;">2</td>
          <td style="width:50%;">3</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td style="width:20%;">2</td>
          <td style="width:30%;">2</td>
          <td style="width:50%;">3</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td style="width:20%;">2</td>
          <td style="width:30%;">2</td>
          <td style="width:50%;">3</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td style="width:20%;">2</td>
          <td style="width:30%;">2</td>
          <td style="width:50%;">3</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td style="width:20%;">2</td>
          <td style="width:30%;">2</td>
          <td style="width:50%;">3</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td style="width:20%;">2</td>
          <td style="width:30%;">2</td>
          <td style="width:50%;">3</td>
        </tr>

      </tbody>
    </table>

  </div>

</body>
```

Comment: I needed not only heder fixed, but the first column too.

Comment: This example shows an approach with two tables in the html: one table renders the header only; the second table renders the rows only but does so within a `div`.  It is the `div` that permits the row-scrolling while the header stays in the same place.  This approach worked for my needs.

Comment: If there is horizontal scrolling too, you need some JS to synchronize the scroll positions of the tables.

Answer (score 4):

To fix both Headers and Columns, you can use the following plugin:

- http://www.fixedheadertable.com/

---

***Updated in July 2019***

Recently is emerged also [a pure CSS solution](https://css-tricks.com/position-sticky-and-table-headers/) that is based on CSS property `position: sticky;` ([here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position) for more details about it) applied onto each `TH` item (instead of their parent container)

Answer (score 4):

I found an excellent solution by Paul O'Brien for the issue and would like share the link:
https://codepen.io/paulobrien/pen/LBrMxa

I removed style for footer:

```css
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}
.intro {
  max-width: 1280px;
  margin: 1em auto;
}
.table-scroll {
  position: relative;
  width:100%;
  z-index: 1;
  margin: auto;
  overflow: auto;
  height: 350px;
}
.table-scroll table {
  width: 100%;
  min-width: 1280px;
  margin: auto;
  border-collapse: separate;
  border-spacing: 0;
}
.table-wrap {
  position: relative;
}
.table-scroll th,
.table-scroll td {
  padding: 5px 10px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
.table-scroll thead th {
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}

th:first-child {
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: sticky;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 2;
  background: #ccc;
}
thead th:first-child {
  z-index: 5;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I recently had to create a solution with a fixed header group and a fixed first column. I split my table into div's and used jquery to capture window scrolling.

http://jsfiddle.net/TinT/EzXub/2346/

```
var prevTop = 0;
var prevLeft = 0;

$(window).scroll(function(event){
  var currentTop = $(this).scrollTop();
  var currentLeft = $(this).scrollLeft();

  if(prevLeft !== currentLeft) {
    prevLeft = currentLeft;
    $('.header').css({'left': -$(this).scrollLeft()})
  }
  if(prevTop !== currentTop) {
    prevTop = currentTop;
    $('.leftCol').css({'top': -$(this).scrollTop() + 40})
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

A co-worker and I have just released a new GitHub project that supplies an Angular directive that you can use to decorate your table with fixed headers: https://github.com/objectcomputing/FixedHeader

It relies on css and angular only, with a directive that adds some divs. There is no jQuery required.

This implementation isn't as fully-featured as some other implementations, but if your need is simply to add fixed tables, we think this might be a good option.

Answer (score 1):

After two days fighting with Internet Explorer 9 + Chrome + Firefox (Windows) and Safari (Mac), I have found a system that is

- Compatible with all these browsers
- Without using javascript
- Using only une div and one table
- Fixed header and footer (Except for IE), with scrollable body. Header and body with same column widths

Result:
[image]

HTML:

```
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="nombre"><%= f.label :cost_center %></th>
      <th class="cabecera cc">Personal</th>
      <th class="cabecera cc">Dpto</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <% @cost_centers.each do |cc| %>
    <tr>
      <td class="nombre"><%= cc.nombre_corto %></td>
      <td class="cc"><%= cc.cacentrocoste %></td>
      <td class="cc"><%= cc.cacentrocoste_dpto %></td>
    </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="3"><a href="#">Mostrar mas usuarios</a></td>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
div.cost_center{
  width:320px;
  font-size:75%;
  margin-left:5px;
  margin-top:5px;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
  float: right;
  display: inline-block;
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  max-height:300px;  
}

div.cost_center label { 
  float:none;
  font-size:14px;
}

div.cost_center table{
  width:300px;
  border-collapse: collapse; 
  float:right;
  table-layout:fixed;
}

div.cost_center table tr{
  height:16px;
}
div.cost_center th{
  font-weight:normal;
}

div.cost_center table tbody{
  display: block;
  overflow: auto;
  max-height:240px;
}

div.cost_center table thead{
  display:block;
}

div.cost_center table tfoot{
  display:block;
}
div.cost_center table tfoot td{
  width:280px;
}
div.cost_center .cc{
  width:60px;
  text-align: center; 
  border: 1px solid #999;
}

div.cost_center .nombre{
  width:150px;
}
div.cost_center tbody .nombre{
  border: 1px solid #999;
}

div.cost_center table tfoot td{
 text-align:center;  
 border: 1px solid #999; 
} 

div.cost_center table th, 
div.cost_center table td { 
  padding: 2px;
  vertical-align: middle; 
}

div.cost_center table tbody td {
  white-space: normal;
  font:  .8em/1.4em Verdana, sans-serif;
  color: #000;
  background-color: white;
}
div.cost_center table th.cabecera { 
  font:  0.8em/1.4em Verdana, sans-serif;
  color: #000;
  background-color: #FFEAB5;
}
```

Comment: Good try, but doesn't work too well for me. In this exemple (http://jsfiddle.net/5ka6e/), the header doesn't resize correctly. This kind of error could eventually ended up have data and header mismatching.

Comment: You forget to add  `div.cost_center table{border-collapse: collapse;}` and the third caption has to be something that fits within the 60px (in this example)

Answer (score 1):

The existing answers will suit most people, but for those who are looking to add **shadows** under the fixed header and to the right of the first (fixed) column, here's a working example (pure css):

http://jsbin.com/nayifepaxo/1/edit?html,output

The main trick in getting this to work is using `::after` to add shadows to the right of each of the first `td` in each `tr`:

```
tr td:first-child:after {
  box-shadow: 15px 0 15px -15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05) inset;
  content: "";
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  bottom:0;
  right:-15px;
  width:15px;
}
```

Took me a while (too long...) to get it all working so I figured I'd share for those who are in a similar situation.

Comment: Did you base this on anyone elses answer and added the shadow?

Answer (score 1):

```css
/* Use overflow:scroll on your container to enable scrolling: */

div {
  max-width: 400px;
  max-height: 150px;
  overflow: scroll;
}


/* Use position: sticky to have it stick to the edge
 * and top, right, or left to choose which edge to stick to: */

thead th {
  position: -webkit-sticky; /* for Safari */
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}

tbody th {
  position: -webkit-sticky; /* for Safari */
  position: sticky;
  left: 0;
}


/* To have the header in the first column stick to the left: */

thead th:first-child {
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}


/* Just to display it nicely: */

thead th {
  background: #000;
  color: #FFF;
}

tbody th {
  background: #FFF;
  border-right: 1px solid #CCC;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td,
th {
  padding: 0.5em;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th>headheadhead</th>
        <th>headheadhead</th>
        <th>headheadhead</th>
        <th>headheadhead</th>
        <th>headheadhead</th>
        <th>headheadhead</th>
        <th>headheadhead</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th>head</th>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>head</th>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>head</th>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>head</th>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>head</th>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>head</th>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
        <td>body</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

need to fix header footer

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution I just made after getting a little confused. seems like some z-index properties need to be set to make this work right and my solution isn't flawless but it works for my application:

crux of the CSS (in SCSS) is setting the properties for the non-sticky elements first to establish the z-index properties.

```
.wrapper {
position: relative;
white-space: nowrap;
overflow: auto;
height: 200px;
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    tbody {
        tr {
            td {
                padding: .5em .75em;
                box-shadow: inset 0px -1px 0px 0px #000000;
                position: relative;
                z-index: -9999;
                background: white;
                &:first-of-type {
                    position: -webkit-sticky;
                    position: sticky;
                    left: 0px;
                    background: #eee;
                    z-index: -999;
                    box-shadow: inset -1px -1px 0px 0px #000000;
                }
            }
            &:first-of-type {
                position: sticky;
                top: 0;
                td {
                    background: #eee; 
                    &:first-of-type {
                        left: 0;
                        top: 0;
                        background: #eee;
                        z-index: 999;
                    }
                }
            }
            &:nth-of-type(2) {
                position: sticky;
                top: calc(1em + 1em + 2px);
                background: white;
                td:first-of-type {
                    position: sticky;
                    left: 0;
                    z-index: 998;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

https://codepen.io/the_Northway/pen/VwMmwXG

Answer (score 0):

Something like this may work for you... It will probably require you to have set column widths for your header row.

```
thead { 
    position: fixed;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vkhNC/

**Update:**

I am not convinced that the example you gave is possible with just CSS.  I would love for someone to prove me wrong.  [Here is what I have so far](http://jsfiddle.net/vkhNC/6/).  It is not the finished product but it could be a start for you.  I hope this points you in a helpful direction, wherever that may be.

Comment: I need not only header, but first column fixed too.

Comment: Problem is headers loose their width. It looks ugly with different header column size and data column size.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to use AngularJS. The AngularUI module has a directive called `ng-grid` which supports a feature called column pinning. It is not 100% pure CSS but neither are the other solutions.

http://angular-ui.github.io/ng-grid/#columnPinning

Answer (score 0):

#### Pure CSS Example:

```
<div id="cntnr">
    <div class="tableHeader">
        <table class="table-header table table-striped table-bordered">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>this</th>
                    <th>transmission</th>
                    <th>is</th>
                    <th>coming</th>
                    <th>to</th>
                    <th>you</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>we've got it...</td>
                    <td>alright you are go</td>
                    <td>uh, we see the Earth now</td>
                    <td>we've got it...</td>
                    <td>alright you are go</td>
                    <td>uh, we see the Earth now</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>


    <div class="tableBody">
        <table class="table-body table table-striped table-bordered">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>this</th>
                    <th>transmission</th>
                    <th>is</th>
                    <th>coming</th>
                    <th>to</th>
                    <th>you</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>we've got it...</td>
                    <td>alright you are go</td>
                    <td>uh, we see the Earth now</td>
                    <td>we've got it...</td>
                    <td>alright you are go</td>
                    <td>uh, we see the Earth now</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>

</div>

#cntnr {
    width: auto;
    height: 200px;
    border: solid 1px #444;
    overflow: auto;
}

.tableHeader {
    position: fixed;
    height: 40px;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-right: 18px;
    background: white;
}

.table-header tbody {
    height: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
}

.table-body thead {
    height: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cCarlson/L98m854d/

**Drawback:** The fixed header structure/logic is fairly dependent upon specific dimensions, so **abstraction is probably not a viable option**.

Comment: Need both fixed header and fixed first column.

Answer (score 0):

Position : sticky doesn't work for some elements like (thead) in chrome and other webkit browsers like safari.

But it works fine with (th)

```css
body {
  background-color: rgba(0, 255, 200, 0.1);
}

.intro {
  color: rgb(228, 23, 23);
}

.wrapper {
  overflow-y: scroll;
  height: 300px;
}

.sticky {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  color: black;
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="container intro">
  <h1>Sticky Table Header</h1>
  <p>Postion : sticky doesn't work for some elements like (thead) in chrome and other webkit browsers like safari. </p>
  <p>But it works fine with (th)</p>
</div>
<div class="container wrapper">
  <table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th class="sticky">Firstname</th>
        <th class="sticky">Lastname</th>
        <th class="sticky">Email</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>James</td>
        <td>Vince</td>
        <td>james@example.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Jonny</td>
        <td>Bairstow</td>
        <td>jonny@example.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>James</td>
        <td>Anderson</td>
        <td>james@example.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Stuart</td>
        <td>Broad</td>
        <td>stuart@example.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Eoin</td>
        <td>Morgan</td>
        <td>eoin@example.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Joe</td>
        <td>Root</td>
        <td>joe@example.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Chris</td>
        <td>Woakes</td>
        <td>chris@example.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Liam</td>
        <td>PLunkett</td>
        <td>liam@example.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Jason</td>
        <td>Roy</td>
        <td>jason@example.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Alex</td>
        <td>Hales</td>
        <td>alex@example.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Jos</td>
        <td>Buttler</td>
        <td>jos@example.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Ben</td>
        <td>Stokes</td>
        <td>ben@example.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Jofra</td>
        <td>Archer</td>
        <td>jofra@example.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Mitchell</td>
        <td>Starc</td>
        <td>mitchell@example.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Aaron</td>
        <td>Finch</td>
        <td>aaron@example.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>David</td>
        <td>Warner</td>
        <td>david@example.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Steve</td>
        <td>Smith</td>
        <td>steve@example.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Glenn</td>
        <td>Maxwell</td>
        <td>glenn@example.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Marcus</td>
        <td>Stoinis</td>
        <td>marcus@example.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Alex</td>
        <td>Carey</td>
        <td>alex@example.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Nathan</td>
        <td>Coulter Nile</td>
        <td>nathan@example.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Pat</td>
        <td>Cummins</td>
        <td>pat@example.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Adam</td>
        <td>Zampa</td>
        <td>zampa@example.com</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Or [visit my codepen example](https://codepen.io/yogavicky/pen/QReepb) :

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution I have just build with css grids based on the answers in here:

https://codesandbox.io/s/sweet-resonance-m733i

Answer (score -1):

I think this will help you:
    https://datatables.net/release-datatables/extensions/FixedHeader/examples/header_footer.html

In a nutshell, if you know how to create a dataTable, You just need to add this jQuery line to your bottom:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var table = $('#example').DataTable();

    new $.fn.dataTable.FixedHeader( table, {
        bottom: true
    } );
} );
```

bottom: true    // is for making the Bottom header fixed as well.

Answer (score -2):

If you only want to use pure HTML and CSS i've got a solution for your problem:
In this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lsAge/vR2qA/5/) you can see a non-script solution that provides a table with a fixed header.
It shouldn't be a problem to adapt the markup for a fixed first column as well.
You would just need to create a absolute-positioned table for the first column inside the `hWrapper`-div and reposition the `vWrapper`-div.
Providing dynamic content should not be a problem using server-side or browser-side tempting-engines, my solution works well in all modern browsers and older browsers from IE8 onwards.

Answer (score -2):

Just need to change style as

```
<table style="position: relative;">
   <thead>
      <thead>
        <tr>
           <th></th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
   </thead>
   <tbody style="position: absolute;height: 300px;overflow:auto;">
      <tr>
         <td></td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

Demo: https://plnkr.co/edit/Qxy5RMJBXmkaJAOjBtQn?p=preview

Comment: in your demo the first column is not fixed