# Fixed scroll at html table header without disturbing header size

Tags: html, css, performance

I am trying to fix the header of html table and scroll the rest of the table body. 
For fixing the column i am using the following css but the problem is that its disturbing the column size of the header .

```
    <style type="text/css">
      div.tableContainer 
       {
        clear: both;
        border: 1px solid #963;
        height: 300px;
        overflow: hidden;
        width: 1000px
       }

        html>body thead.fixedHeader tr 
        {
        display: block
       }


   thead.fixedHeader th 
    {

        background: #C96;
    border-left: 1px solid #EB8;
    border-right: 1px solid #B74;
    border-top: 1px solid #EB8;
    font-weight: normal;
    padding: 4px 3px;
    text-align: left
        position: relative
        width: 200px

    }

        html>body tbody.scrollContent {
        display: block;
        height: 300px;
        overflow: auto;
        width: 100%

       }

     tbody.scrollContent td, tbody.scrollContent tr.normalRow td {

        background: #FFF;
    border-bottom: none;
    border-left: none;
    border-right: 1px solid #CCC;
    border-top: 1px solid #DDD;
        padding: 2px 3px 3px 4px

      }

       html>body thead.fixedHeader th +th {
    width: 50px
       }


     </style>
```

Comment: Take a look at this thread,  
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8232713/how-to-display-scroll-bar-onto-a-html-table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Related posts

1) [Table with fixed header and fixed column on pure css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15811653/table-with-fixed-header-and-column-on-pure-css)

2) [Scrollable table](http://www.imaputz.com/cssStuff/bigFourVersion.html)

3) [How to display scroll bar onto a html table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8232713/how-to-display-scroll-bar-onto-a-html-table)

4) [Various Tables also there are some of them - with fixed header](http://salzerdesign.com/test/fixedTable.html) css you can find in html page if you inspect it

hope it would help you

Answer (score 0):

Put the header in a separate table and the content in another, but position both the tables together so that it looks like one table.

```
<table>
put headers here.
</table>
<table>
put content here.
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using css property overflow:overlay