# table layout fixed - when th position is absolute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, html-table

I have table inside a div,

```
 <div class="divScroll">
  <table class="table1">
  <tr class="tableHeader">
   <th>Header1</th>
   <th>Header2</th>
   <th>Header3</th>
   <th>Header4</th>
   <th>Header5</th>
   </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>Data1</td>
   <td>Data2</td>
   <td>Data3</td>
   <td>Data4</td>
   <td>Data5</td>
   </tr>
   .....
   .....
  </table>
 </div>
```

My CSS,

```
 .divScroll
 {
   height: 25px;
   overflow-y: auto;
   width: 100%
 }

 .table1
 {
   width: 100%;
   table-layout: fixed;
 }

 .tableHeader
 {
   position: absolute;
 }
```

In the above coed, I am trying to make table scrollable with fixed header. That means when user scroll top-> bottom table header should remain fixed only table data should be scrolled.

I can achieve, scrollable table but problem is th col width are not aligned with td col width Since i applied Position : absolute for 'th'.

How to make both th and td col width aligned properly?

Comment: Fixed table header isn't as easy as you thought, try googling "fixed table header" and follow a solution that works for you.

Answer (score 0):

It is a very common question, already answered in the past.

Here some local resources:

- [Table header to stay fixed at the top when user scrolls it out of view with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4709390/table-header-to-stay-fixed-at-the-top-when-user-scrolls-it-out-of-view-with-jque)
- [Table with fixed header and fixed column on pure css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15811653/table-with-fixed-header-and-fixed-column-on-pure-css)

And here another external:

- [Fixed Header Table](http://www.fixedheadertable.com/)