# Freeze the first 2 rows of a table

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have seen Jquery plugins and CSS styles to freeze the header of a table. Is there any to Freeze the first two rows. My second row contains a text box for search. I can't give fixed width for rows.

```
 <table>
 <thead>
  <tr>
     <th>Month</th>
     <th>Savings</th>
  </tr>
 </thead>
<tbody>
  <tr>
     <td><input type="text"/></td>
     <td><input type="text"/></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td>February</td>
     <td>$80</td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Can you use DataTables?

Comment: what do you mean by "freeze" ?

Comment: @Aziz Frozen Headers. Fixed Headers.

Comment: well, what happens when you add `position: fixed;` then? you can target the first table rows with CSS using `tr:nth-child(-n+2)` pseudo selector

Comment: Whatever CSS styles are applied to the header row by those plugins will also need to be applied to `tbody tr:first-child`.

Comment: The adjacent row disappears when I give position fixed

Comment: @MattBrowne when I use a plugin and while the page is rendered when I inspect what I see is another table is formed just for the header part, instead of css styling

Comment: OK Maybe you can help us understand what you are trying to achieve by showing us a demo or something similar

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/onxzsqjv/ in this fiddle I have created a table. what I want is the First 2 rows ie the Header row and Row containing text box to be fixed while scrolling.

Comment: Have you tried putting the second row inside `<thead>` also and using the plugin you mentioned? Even if that doesn't work, it's probably more semantically correct for the second row to be inside `<thead>`.

Comment: When I put the second row inside thead the css styling breaks

Comment: In my experience, there's always a gotcha trying this sort of thing with CSS. I opted to use [DataTables](https://datatables.net/). It clones bits and pieces, but I believe it does so in an accessible way and also has a number of useful plugins to extend / provide more functionality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like @KarlDawson's suggestion of using [DataTables](https://datatables.net/) will work. Here's a working demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/C8Dtf/1903/

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="display" id="example">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Rendering engine</th>
            <th>Browser</th>
            <th>Platform(s)</th>
            <th>Engine version</th>
            <th>CSS grade</th>
        </tr>
        <!-- 2nd header row that will also be frozen -->
        <tr>
            <th>2Rendering engine</th>
            <th>2Browser</th>
            <th>2Platform(s)</th>
            <th>2Engine version</th>
            <th>2CSS grade</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr class="gradeX">
            <td>Trident</td>
            <td>Internet
                 Explorer 4.0</td>
            <td>Win 95+</td>
            <td class="center">4</td>
            <td class="center">X</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="gradeC">
            <td>Trident</td>
            <td>Internet
                 Explorer 5.0</td>
            <td>Win 95+</td>
            <td class="center">5</td>
            <td class="center">C</td>
        </tr>
        ...
    </tbody>
</table>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready( function () 
{
    var iStart = new Date().getTime();
    var oTable = $('#example').dataTable( 
    {
        "sScrollY": "300px",
        "sScrollX": "100%",
        "sScrollXInner": "150%",
        "bScrollCollapse": true,
        "bPaginate": false,
        "bFilter": false
    } );
    new FixedColumns( oTable, 
    {
        "sHeightMatch": "none"
    } );
} );
```

Adapted from this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15826692/560114. I'm not familiar with the details of the DataTable plugin, but it should be possible to adapt your HTML so that it works similarly to this demo.

Answer (score 0):

**I think you want something like this-**

This is pure css no other script is needed..

Checkout this url:

codepen.io/mastershine/pen/gPdaPL

Comment: Hi, webmasteravi. Please read “[How do I write a good answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)”

Comment: @webmasteravi In the example the second row is not fixed (freezed) it moves upwards on scrolling.

Comment: @webmasteravi external links without accompanying code excerpts are problematic because sometimes links to down or are unavailable...and answers on SO should be at least somewhat complete without depending on external links.