# How to resize table cells with fixed header

Tags: javascript, css

I am building a html table with > 100 rows, for what I'd like the table head to stay visible. The user should have the possibility to resize the cells via mouse click in the frontend; As seen [here](https://www.brainbell.com/javascript/making-resizable-table-js.html).

I've tried to use `display: block` to fix the first row.
But when I use JavaScript to resize the table, all `th` from `thead` show up within width of first column of `tbody`. It's probably related to the absolut-position in JS.

```css
table thead tr {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
}

table tbody {
  display: block;
  overflow: auto;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
}
```

For now users can only adjust size of `th`, which is per default shrinked to the width of first column from `tbody`. I'd like the user to click anywhere in the table to change the whole column-width, `th` and `td`; the first row (`thead`) has to be always fixed and visible.

Comment: `display block` will break your display because tables use `display: table`. I can almost get it to work giving the thead `position: fixed` but that breaks how the table layout is calculated

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Table with fixed header and fixed column on pure css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15811653/table-with-fixed-header-and-fixed-column-on-pure-css)

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution on Google:

Now, I've wrapped the table into another `div` and added following JS

```js
document.getElementById("myDiv").addEventListener("scroll",function(){
   var translate = "translate(0,"+this.scrollTop+"px)";
   this.querySelector("thead").style.transform = translate;
});
```

Set the `div` properties to `overflow: auto; background-color: white;` and you're good to go!

Comment: The `scroll` event gets called very frequently. It would be better to cache the `thead` element outside the event callback. Reduces the `querySelector` calls to a minimum and helps performance.