# Clarity Design Table component sticky header

Tags: css, angular, vmware-clarity

I am using the table component from Clarity Design v2. Is there a way to make the vertical header and horizontal header to freeze while scrolling the table or page?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15811653/table-with-fixed-header-and-fixed-column-on-pure-css

Comment: @Eliseo links to one solution that the app can implement to add on style for the table header and first column of the table.Clarity tables are not styled to have fixed headers and first columns by default.