# Horizontal and vertical scroll with fixed header and left div

Tags: html, css, angular

Here a simplified version of what I got :

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9-0-0-rc-1-scrollable?file=src/app/app.component.html

So for now, I have a horizontal scroll. The 1st left div (blue) is fixed and must not be affected by the horizontal scroll. Only yellow and pink divs are scrollable with horizontal scroll.

What I need now is to set a vertical scroll. This scroll must allow to scroll both blue and pink divs, the yellow one must be fixed, not affected by vertical scroll.

I don't know how to accomplish this.

My app use Angular 9. I've tried to set a vertical scroll in both blue and pink divs, and synchronise them together but it's not ok as there's a small time between the moment that user scrolls in a div and moment that the scroll is reported to the other div, and I need it to be seamless.

I tried with the cdkScrollable, same issue.

Also this page can contains a huge amount of data, latence is expected, so I cannot rely on scroll synchronization.

Any idea?

Many thx

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Table with fixed header and fixed column on pure css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15811653/table-with-fixed-header-and-fixed-column-on-pure-css)

Comment: Hi, I could manage to adapt this to my case, many thx =)