# How do I create an HTML responsive table with first 3 fixed/frozen left column and a scrollable body in angular 11?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, angular11, angular-bootstrap

I'm working on angular 11 and ng-bootstrap 9.1 and i need to make a table with first 3 columns fixed and at the same time it should be responsive too, I've made it fixed but couldn't find a foolproof solution to make it responsive (ui breaks at some points).

I know this question is similar to some other questions, like:

- [HTML table with fixed headers and a fixed column?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/684211/html-table-with-fixed-headers-and-a-fixed-column)
- [How can I lock the first row and first column of a table when scrolling, possibly using JavaScript and CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/296020/how-can-i-lock-the-first-row-and-first-column-of-a-table-when-scrolling-possibly)
- [How do I create an HTML table with a fixed/frozen left column and a scrollable body?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1312236/how-do-i-create-an-html-table-with-a-fixed-frozen-left-column-and-a-scrollable-b)

I'm looking for a simple solution, like;

- is there any other ways in angular or ng-bootstrap to make it happen?
- or is there any way that's pretty much fool proof in a responsive way?

*can't add external dependancies or anything.*

**Html in component to create the table**

```
<div class="row mb-2 view" *ngIf="value1.length">
    <div class="col-md-12 mb-2 wrapper" style="max-height: 65vh; overflow-y: auto;">
        <table class="bg-white roundedCorner table-sm table table-bordered">
            <tr class="font-weight-bolder text-monospace" style="background-color: aliceblue; font-size: 1em;">
                <th class="text-center align-middle sticky-col check-box" rowspan="2" *ngIf="####" >                                 <input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="checkAll" (click)="fnCall($event)">                             </th>
                <th rowspan="2" class="text-center align-middle sticky-col first-col" [ngStyle]="{'left': lockMode?'80px':'0px'}" style="background-color: aliceblue;">                                 Chest Number                               </th>
                <th  rowspan="2" class="text-center align-middle sticky-col  second-col"  [ngStyle]="{'left': lockMode?'180px':'100px'}" style="background-color: aliceblue;">                                 Project Name                             </th>
                <th  [attr.colspan]="rubrics.length" class="text-center align-middle">                                 Rubrics                             </th>
                <th class="text-center align-middle"rowspan="2" style="max-width: 80px;">                                 Total Mark                             </th>
                <th class="text-center align-middle" rowspan="2">                                 Remarks                             </th>
            </tr>
            <tr class="text-monospace text-center align-middle font-italic font-bold" style="background-color: azure;" >
                <th *ngFor="let rubric of rubrics">                                     {{ rubric.rubricName }} ({{rubric.maxMark}})                                </th>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

**css code**  I've used to make it fixed

```
.view {
    margin: auto;
    width: auto;
    border-collapse: separate;
        border-spacing: 0;
  }
.wrapper {
    position: relative;
    overflow: auto;
    white-space: nowrap;
  }
  
  .sticky-col {
    position: -webkit-sticky;
    position: sticky;
  }
  
  .first-col {
    width: 100px;
    min-width: 100px;
    max-width: 100px;
  }
  
  .second-col {
    width: 20vw;
    min-width: 20vw;
    max-width: 20vw;
  }
  .check-box {
    width: 25px;
    min-width: 25px;
    max-width: 25px;
    left: 0px;
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case, it was the CSS and inline styles that was the problem; instead of adding classes for every column I needed, I used `:nth-child()` for the first two columns and added inline styles based on conditions for that, obviously, I used `ng-style` to address the condition. So the code will be like this:-

```css
/* CSS */  
  th:first-child, td:first-child{
    position: sticky;
    left: -1px;
    width: 40px;
  }

  td:nth-child(2), th:nth-child(2){
    position: sticky;
  }
```

```html
<!--HTML-->
<tr class="font-weight-bolder text-monospace " style="background-color: aliceblue; font-size: 1em;">
   <th class="text-center align-middle " style="background-color: aliceblue; z-index: 33" rowspan="2" *ngIf="lockMode">
  <input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="checkAll" (click)="selectAllProjectsCheckChange($event)">
   </th>
   <th rowspan="2" class="text-center align-middle " [ngStyle]="{'left': lockMode? '20px' :'0px'}" style="background-color: aliceblue; z-index: 33;">
  Chest Number
   </th>
   <th  rowspan="2" class="text-center align-middle" [ngStyle]="{'left': lockMode?'76px':'55px'}"  style="background-color: aliceblue; position: sticky; z-index: 33">
  Project Name
   </th>
</tr>
<tr class="text-center align-middle sticky-col" *ngFor="let project of projectMappings">
   <!-- *ngIf="project.pending" -->
   <ng-container *ngIf="isShowPendingEnabled? !project.isValid : true">
  <td class="text-center align-middle" *ngIf="lockMode" style="z-index: 33 ; background-color: white;">
     <input type="checkbox" [disabled]="project.judgeDetails.status? project.judgeDetails.status === 'locked': false" [checked]="(project.judgeDetails.status? project.judgeDetails.status === 'locked': false) || checkLockValid(project._id)" (click)="projectLockCheckboxChange(project)">
  </td>
  <td class="text-center align-middle" style="z-index: 33 ; background-color: white;" [ngStyle]="{'left': lockMode?'20px':'0px'}">
     {{ project.chestNumber? project.chestNumber : 'N/A'}}
  </td>
  <td class="text-center align-middle" style="z-index: 33 ; background-color: white; position: sticky;" [ngStyle]="{'left': lockMode?'76px':'55px'}" >
     {{ project.projectName }}
  </td>
   </ng-container>
</tr>
```