# Fix thead on page scroll

Tags: jquery

Situation: 
A page with a table with several rows.
I want to fix thead when thead reach the top of the page when scrolling, using jquery or any given scripting.
I don't want to overflow the table itself.

Comment: I wrote a plugin that does this using fixed or absolute position. While the code in the answer works for *that* table, it will not work for all many tables, for example tables with colspans or hidden columns. Try this instead: http://mkoryak.github.io/floatThead/

Comment: https://github.com/karaxuna/fixed-table-header

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use Lobstrosity's code with a slight modification: `position: fixed` instead of `absolute`.

`position: fixed` is now widely adopted by all browsers including IE8 and onwards. BTW fixed renders much nicer on mobile/tablet devices than `position: absolute`.

I found that on a table with dynamic widths for each column, the absolutely positioned <thead> would lose the widths of the rest of the columns, so to fix this I came up with the following code:

**What this code does is as follows:**

Determines the widths of each column in your table by looking up the CSS widths of the first <tbody> <tr> <td> row and storing these in an array for later. When the user scrolls the class 'fixed' is added to the <thead> (Default browser behaviour will alter the widths of the <th>'s and they won't match up with the <tbody>. So to fix this we retroactively set the widths of the <th> to the values we've read earlier.

Anyway here's the code:

**CSS**

```
table.entries {width: 100%;border-spacing: 0px;margin:0;}
table.entries thead.fixed {position:fixed;top:0;}
```

**HTML**

```
<table class="entries" id="entriestable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th>Location</th>
            <th>DOB</th>
            <th>Opt&nbsp;in</th>
            <th>Added</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="name">Ricky Bobby</td>
            <td>ricky.bobby@email.com</td>
            <td class="addy"><i>Kent, GB</i></td>
            <td class="dob">20/08/1984</td>
            <td>Yes</td>
            <td class="date">4 hours ago</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**JavaScript**

```
TableThing = function(params) {
    settings = {
        table: $('#entriestable'),
        thead: []
    };

    this.fixThead = function() {
        // empty our array to begin with
        settings.thead = [];
        // loop over the first row of td's in &lt;tbody> and get the widths of individual &lt;td>'s
        $('tbody tr:eq(1) td', settings.table).each( function(i,v){
            settings.thead.push($(v).width());
        });

        // now loop over our array setting the widths we've got to the &lt;th>'s
        for(i=0;i<settings.thead.length;i++) {
            $('thead th:eq('+i+')', settings.table).width(settings.thead[i]);
        }

        // here we attach to the scroll, adding the class 'fixed' to the &lt;thead> 
        $(window).scroll(function() {
            var windowTop = $(window).scrollTop();

            if (windowTop > settings.table.offset().top) {
                $("thead", settings.table).addClass("fixed");
            }
            else {
                $("thead", settings.table).removeClass("fixed");
            }
        });
    }
}
$(function(){
    var table = new TableThing();
    table.fixThead();
    $(window).resize(function(){
        table.fixThead();
    });
});
```

Comment: If you have multiple tables you need to pass the `#entriestable` id as a parameter and declare the local variable settings inside the function `var settings = { table: $(params.id), thead: [] }`

Answer (score 5):

Here's something that *kind of* works (quickly tested in FF 3.5, Chrome 3, and IE 8) that you might be able to tailor to your needs.

It uses absolute positioning of the `thead`. When the `thead` becomes absolutely positioned, this basically removes it from the original flow of the `table` and the widths of all the `tbody` `td`s adjust accordingly. So you get ugly behavior if you don't specify column widths or if any column's header is wider than any other cell in that column.

**CSS**

```
#Grid thead.Fixed
{
    position: absolute;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<table id="Grid">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>A</td>
            <td>B</td>
            <td>C</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
        </tr>
        <!-- etc. -->
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(function() {
    var table = $("#Grid");

    $(window).scroll(function() {
        var windowTop = $(window).scrollTop();

        if (windowTop > table.offset().top) {
            $("thead", table).addClass("Fixed").css("top", windowTop);
        }
        else {
            $("thead", table).removeClass("Fixed");
        }
    });
});
```

I noticed that it does not work in IE unless you specify a strict XHTML doctype:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html>
    <!-- etc. -->
```

Comment: yes, i started using a fixed position, and that ugly behavior took me to ask for a solution here, to save time. by now, yours is the solution! thank you.

Answer (score 3):

**Much easier solution in 2020:**

The CSS `position: sticky` now has pretty good browser support.

See: https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sticky

You can't apply `position: sticky` to either `<thead>` or `<tr>`.

*But you **can** make a `<thead>` sticky by applying the following CSS to `<th>`:*

```
th {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}
```

**Working Example:**

```css
.tableContainer {
  width: 360px;
  border: 1px solid rgb(127, 127, 127);
  max-height: 180px;
  overflow: auto;
}

table {
  width: 100%;
}

th {
  position: sticky;
  top: 4px;
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 0);
  outline: 2px solid rgb(255, 255, 255);
  transform: translateY(-2px);
}

td {
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
}

tr,
td {
  border: 1px solid rgb(191, 191, 191);
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

tr:nth-of-type(odd) td:nth-of-type(odd),
tr:nth-of-type(even) td:nth-of-type(even) {
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
}
```

```html
<div class="tableContainer">

<table>
<thead>
<tr>
<th>This</th>
<th>thead</th>
<th>is</th>
<th>now</th>
<th>sticky</th>
</tr>
</thead>

<tbody>
<tr>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>


<tr>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>


<tr>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>


<tr>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
(function ($) {
    $.fn.fixedHeader = function () {
        return this.filter('table').each(function () {
            var that = this;
            var $head = $('<div></div>').addClass('head');
            $(this).before($head);
            $('th', this).each(function () {
                var $el = $(this);
                var $div = $('<div></div>').width($el.outerWidth()).text(
                $el.text());
                $head.append($div);
            });
            $(window).on('scroll', function () {
                var $that = $(that);
                var w = $(window).scrollTop();
                var o = $('th', that).first().offset().top;
                var tableO = $that.offset().top + $that.height();
                if (o < w && tableO > w) {
                    $head.show();
                } else {
                    $head.hide();
                }
            });
        });
    };
})(jQuery);
```

You can use this jquery plugin (you need to adapt .head style to your thead style). Working example here: http://jsfiddle.net/lukasi/7K52p/1/

Comment: and what happens if your th changes width?

Comment: @PirateApp yes you would need to recalculate the width of divs, or just remove div.head and call fixedHeader on table again