# Limiting Fixed THEAD on page scroll upto TABLE or Specific DIV height

Tags: jquery

I am setting up a comparison table & wanted to have fixed THEAD when user scrolls down since its a very long text.

I found a solution to it here https://stackoverflow.com/a/9669008/1463443. It works as desired.

However, since my page's footer is bulky - a further scroll down still shows the fixed THEAD beyond the table content.

I want to limit this fixed THEAD up to this table height or preferably up to #CONTENT div id (should not be seen on #Footer)

This is the code I am using

**CSS**

```
table.entries {width: 100%;border-spacing: 0px;margin:0;}
table.entries thead.fixed {position:fixed;top:0;}
```

**Javascript**

```
TableThing = function(params) {
settings = {
    table: $('#table'),
    thead: []
};

this.fixThead = function() {
    // empty our array to begin with
    settings.thead = [];
    // loop over the first row of td's in &lt;tbody> and get the widths of individual &lt;td>'s
    $('tbody tr:eq(1) td', settings.table).each( function(i,v){
        settings.thead.push($(v).width());
    });

    // now loop over our array setting the widths we've got to the &lt;th>'s
    for(i=0;i<settings.thead.length;i++) {
        $('thead th:eq('+i+')', settings.table).width(settings.thead[i]);
    }

    // here we attach to the scroll, adding the class 'fixed' to the &lt;thead> 
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        var windowTop = $(window).scrollTop();

        if (windowTop > settings.table.offset().top) {
            $("thead", settings.table).addClass("fixed");
        }
        else {
            $("thead", settings.table).removeClass("fixed");
        }
    });
}
}
$(function(){
var table = new TableThing();
table.fixThead();
$(window).resize(function(){
    table.fixThead();
});
});
```

Comment: you better show your code to get more chances to receive answers..

Comment: Thanks. I did as u suggested :)