# Can I make header of a table fixed without jquery, only by CSS?

Tags: html, css

Is there a way that I can make my Table header fixed without using any Javascript, by using just CSS?

Comment: This [question is asking for a non-javascript version](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3338758/html-fixed-header-table-scrollbar). This [page shows different approaches](http://salzerdesign.com/test/fixedTable.html). This [question is asking for html5 css only approach](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17584702/how-to-add-a-scrollbar-to-an-html5-table)

Answer (score 0):

How about:

CSS:

```
thead {
position: fixed;
}
```

HTML:

```
<table>
<thead></thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Now, any tag called `<thead>` will automatically be fixed. If you only want specific tags to be fixed, then try:

CSS:

```
.tofix {
position:fixed;
}
```

HTML:

```
 <table>
    <thead class="tofix"></thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
    <td>
    </td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
```

Then any tag with the classname will be fixed. On a side note: doing `thead.tofix` in CSS will make so that only `<thead>` tags can have that class.

Comment: This does not work as intended.