# How do I make a fixed header, fixed width, scrollable table which is wider than the screen without using Javascript?

Tags: html, scroll, fixed-width, fixed-header-tables

Haven't found anything satisfactory for this particular problem, although it has been asked many times. I've found a possible solution, but it requires the vertical scroll bar to move to the left hand side of the screen. Not ideal, but works fine in my **specific** case. Please, no comments on this being a bad idea unless you have a specific solution that fulfils the rest of my requirements.

Here are the specifics for my problem:

- HTML / CSS only - there is a lot of data and the JavaScript scrolling that I've found are much too slow and unresponsive. Javascript can be used for one time formatting operations as long as it's not operating on all the data rows.
- Must be able to scroll rows up and down while headers remain fixed.
- Width of each column should be fixed
- Vertical and horizontal scroll bars should be visible

[Problem Example](http://jsbin.com/uxaxe3/3): This table does everything I need except for one issue - the vertical scroll bar is not visible without scrolling horizontally.

[Current Solution](http://jsbin.com/opeco5/3): This solves my specific problem, but I don't think it will work for everyone. Any better solutions?

Answer (score 1):

This is a pure css cross browser support solution for you :

[Pure CSS Scrollable Table with Fixed Header](http://www.imaputz.com/cssStuff/bigFourVersion.html)

you can also visit this stack overflow thread :

[HTML table with fixed headers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/673153/html-table-with-fixed-headers)

Comment: Thanks, but those solutions were the reason I created this post -  neither of them worked well for my application. The CSS Scrollable Table worked poorly for me once the table became wider than the page. The Stack Overflow thread solutions (that I tried) also worked poorly with wide tables (for my application at least).