# How to freeze cols and rows in Orbeon Form Runner?

Tags: orbeon

I've a form with 500+ cells. How to freeze top row and left col, like Excel does?
Is it possible?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! We encourage you to [research your questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). If you've [tried something already](http://whathaveyoutried.com/), please add it to the question - if not, research and attempt your question first, and then come back.

Answer (score 0):

This is not something that XForms helps with. For this, you need to write CSS/HTML. See for instance the answers to the question on how to [freeze the top row for an html table only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8423768/freeze-the-top-row-for-an-html-table-only).